# How to setup a Wireless Access-Point using my laptop's WiFi card?

Tags: 10.10, internet, android, wireless-access-point

want to share my Laptops (running Ubuntu 10.10) Broadband with my Android (Galaxy Mini) running 2.2.1. Since Androids currently do not support ad-hoc networks so the "Create new wireless network.." won't help.

Q1) How do i setup a Wireless Access Point using my Laptops WiFi card? Q2) What is the difference between an "ad-hoc" network and an "access point"?

```
**abdulkarim@aK-laptop**:~$ lspci | grep ireless 
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)



iw list
Wiphy phy0
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x11ce
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * ** AP
         * AP/VLAN**
         * monitor
         * mesh point
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * new_beacon
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_params
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * Unknown command (55)
         * Unknown command (57)
         * Unknown command (59)
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * Unknown command (65)
         * connect
         * disconnect
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)

Answer (score 2):

Not all wireless cards support **Access Point** mode. Check to make sure your card does, before you frustrate yourself in software.

Comment: how can I check that ?

Answer (score 1):

OpenWRT uses `hostapd` to provide its services.  It is available for Utuntu.

You will need to arrange for masquerading and firewalling as well.  I like Shorewall for things like that.  In your case the two-interface model should work well.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Any method to backup my current network configuration so that if i screw-up i may be able to revert to my original settings :P

Comment: @Abdul: If you are using /etc/network/interfaces, then you can just copy it.  If you are using NetworkManager, your configuration should be in the /etc/NetworkManager directory tree.  I think the system-connections directory will have your configuration.