# How to setup a Wireless Access-Point using my laptops WiFi card?

Tags: 10.10, laptop, android, adhoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to setup a Wireless Access-Point using my laptop's WiFi card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35060/how-to-setup-a-wireless-access-point-using-my-laptops-wifi-card)

I want to share my Laptops (running Ubuntu 10.10) Broadband with my Android (Galaxy Mini) running 2.2.1. Since Androids currently do not support ad-hoc networks so the "Create new wireless network.." won't help.

Q1) How do i setup a Wireless Access Point using my Laptops WiFi card?
Q2) What is the difference between an "ad-hoc" network and an "access point"?

```
**abdulkarim@aK-laptop**:~$ lspci | grep ireless 
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)



iw list
Wiphy phy0
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x11ce
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (passive scanning)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * ** AP
         * AP/VLAN**
         * monitor
         * mesh point
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * new_beacon
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_params
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * Unknown command (55)
         * Unknown command (57)
         * Unknown command (59)
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * Unknown command (65)
         * connect
         * disconnect
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to provide a wifi connection from Ubuntu to my Android phone, but there are two issues:
1) You cannot share a wifi connection. That means that your laptop needs to be cable-connected by ethernet. There are exceptions, but the vast majority of wifi cards don't seem to be able to be connected to two networks at once. 
2) This only seems to work without wifi security. When I go to the NetworkManager icon and select `Create New Wireless Network`, I set `Security` to `None` and give the network a name. My Motorola milestone (Android 2.3) then connects. This is not ideal, but I would start with no security and then try to enable security, if your phone will use it.

Comment: this would create an ad-hoc network but Android2.2 doesn't support ad-hoc networks :(