# How to create a Wi-Fi Hotspot (in Access Point mode)?

Tags: wireless, hot-spot, wireless-access-point, ap-hotspot

How to setup an Access Point (AP) mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?

> **Point to be noted**: Wireless access points aren't the same as ad hoc networks. They differ significantly. In short, ad hoc networks aren't supported on newer devices and most Android, Windows Phone and Blackberry devices (and maybe iOS devices too), whereas AP mode Wi-Fi hotspots are. To get an idea about AP mode hotspots, ad hoc networks and their difference, refer to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point#Wireless_access_point_vs._ad_hoc_network).

Comment: iOS devises does support ad-hoc networks. But they disconnect whenever you turn off the screen.

Comment: Third party apps can allow ad-hoc network wifi on rooted android devices.

Comment: WEP does not work for Android phones. WPA does.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

## Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and newer

With GNOME 3.36 desktop on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, WiFi tethering has become easier than ever! Just open the *Wi-Fi Settings* from system menu.

[image: System Menu]

In the *Wi-Fi Settings* window, click on the drop-down menu on top right and select *Turn On Wi-Fi Hotspot* option.

[image: Turn On WiFi Hotspot]

A dialog will show up, where you can set the name and password for your new hotspot.

[image: Set name and password for hotspot]

If your hotspot gets created successfully, *Wi-Fi Settings* would now show a section with a toggle for the newly created hotspot.

[image: Newly created hotspot]

A hotspot indicator would appear on the top bar as well, showing it's active status.

[image: Active hotspot indicator]

If you need to edit the hotspot and do more advanced configuration, follow instructions similar to that of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS described below.

## Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

GNOME 3.28 desktop on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS makes it easy to start a WiFi hotspot. Open the *Wi-Fi Settings* from system menu.

[image: GNOME system status menu]

And then from the hamburger menu on Wi-Fi Settings, select *Turn On Wi-Fi Hotspot*. That's it, your WiFi access point is now up and running!

[image: WiFi Settings]

### Advanced Stuff

If you wanna change the name (SSID) and password of your access point, open *Network Connections* editor tool by entering the following in either *Terminal* or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>:

```
nm-connection-editor
```

[image: Network Connections]

Double click on Hotspot and the editor window'll appear. You may change SSID and password from the Wi-Fi and Wi-Fi Security tabs.

[image: Edit SSID]
[image: Edit password]

## Ubuntu 16.04 LTS & 14.04 LTS

### Step 1: Test whether your WiFi card supports AP mode

Follow the **Access Point mode check** in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode/180734#180734) provided by [Web-E](https://askubuntu.com/users/35775/web-e)

### Step 2: Start the built-in Hotspot

*Network* comes with a built-in option to start an Ad-Hoc hotspot. So, let's use this first, so that it could be configured and converted to an Access Point mode hotspot in the next step.

Search *Network* in Dash and open it.

[image: DashSearch]

Press the "*Use as Hotspot*" button and *Network Manager* will start an AdHoc hotspot.

[image: Hotspot]

But that's not what we want, is it?  Stop the hotspot.

### Step 3: Configure Hotspot

Open *Network Connections* from Dash or '*Edit Connections*' from Network Indicator menu.

[image: Edit Connections]

In the *Network Connections* window that appears, there'll be a connection named *Hotspot* listed under the WiFi section. Select it and click the '*Edit*' button.

[image: Network Connections]

In the window that appears, you may edit the broadcast name (SSID) of your hotspot. Now comes the most important part of this configuration: change mode to '*Hotspot*', which'll finally convert the hotspot to Access Point mode. Users of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS'll notice that this mode isn't available to choose from the dropdown. Don't get disappointed, as you can still do it via an extra *Step 3.1*.

[image: Edit Hotspot Name and Password]

Save and open the same *Editing Hotspot* window again. This time go to the *WiFi Security* tab for selecting password type. If you don't want to set a password, you can set security to none and thus create an open hotspot. If you're setting a password, it's recommended to change the security key from WEP to WPA2. Once the configurations are done, don't forget to save it so that the changes could apply.

In the *General* tab, make sure that “Automatically connect to this network when it is available” is turned off (unless you only ever use your wifi as a hotspot). Otherwise, since the hotspot is always available, you won't see the menu entries to connect to other wifi networks in the network manager applet.

### Step 3.1: Only for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Since Ubuntu 14.04 LTS's *Networks* (`network-manager v9.8.8`) doesn't offer a graphical setting to select AP mode, we'll manually edit it's config file to force the conversion. Copy the following command, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or open *Terminal* and paste it there:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot
```

Type your password in the authorization dialog that appears and the configuration file will be opened in text editor. Find a line beginning with `mode=`, change it to `mode=ap` and save the file.

### Step 4: Start Hotspot

Now that the configuration part is over, we'll start the hotspot. Click on '*Create New Wi-Fi Network*' from Network Indicator menu.

[image: Create New WiFi Connection]

In the window that appears, click on the connection drop-down button and change "New..." to "Hotspot". Press the "Create" button and your hotspot will start running. From now on, whenever you need a hotspot, you just need to do this step i.e **Step 4** only.

[image: Start Hotspot]

K.. That's all folks! Have fun with your new Access Point

Comment: Coolest easy steps @HEXcube

Comment: I had completed the 3 steps described by @Web-E but my android phone wouldn't connect, perennially trying to "obtain ip address." Then I just did the "mode=ap" change in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/my_wifi_connection_name suggested by HEXcube and got connected instantly. My Ubuntu is 13.10 64bit on Acer laptop Aspire E1-531.

Comment: The ip_forward and masquerade commands were executed as part of Web-E's steps - should we revoke them? If yes, how?

Comment: I wish more people knew about this solution. This should be the preferred answer.

Comment: [The solution below](http://askubuntu.com/a/602910/266507) using KDE connection editor worked for me. However, the solution in this article didn't, because it miss very important thing: to what value should be IPv4 tab set? I have «Automatic(DHCP)», which on start ends up with spamming syslog with «DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255» for ≈5 seconds, and then disconnecting because of timeout. *(I didn't try the variant with hostapd though)*

Comment: @Hi-Angel  If you followed **Step 1** and started the built-in _Hotpsot_ first, then there's **NO NEED** to manually edit IPv4 settings. Just leave _Hotspot_'s default IPv4 setting (_"Shared to other computers"_) as it is.

Comment: @HEXcube ah, well, of course I didn't start that, because you titled **Step 1** as «Test whether your WiFi card supports AP mode», which I don't need because I know that it does :Ь Btw, the default IPv4 settings were just «Automatic(DHCP)», not the "Shared to other computers" *(perhaps because of the first step)*.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Oh, I meant **Step 2**! My bad!  By the way, which Ubuntu release are you using?  I haven't tested on 15.10 yet. Will update the answer when 16.04LTS is out. 

Comment: @HEXcube ah, well, it still isn't obvious. It is written, like "start hotspot" is the easy way, but for those who don't seek ones, below is another one. I have a Kubuntu-14.04.03, though I do use Awesome WM *(due to low RAM without KDE, so I'm using `nm-applet`)*. Thank you! ☺

Comment: I'm trying this on 15.10.  It didn't work at first until I installed `hostapd`.  Now it connects, but doesn't seem to be allocating an IP address.    I tried installing `isc-dhcp-server` but it didn't make any difference.  dnsmasq seems to be running with some dhcp ranges but not allocating to the wlan0 interface.  What could have gone wrong?

Comment: @tudor Sorry for the late reply, but I updated the answer for Ubuntu 16.04LTS! So, can u give this a try on Ubuntu 16.04LTS? 

Comment: @HEXcude, Thanks, but really needed an answer for 15.10.  I haven't yet got the kernel working properly on 16.04 yet due to the shift to I2S audio. :-(

Comment: @HEXcube - no, these steps don't work on 16.04 for me. Everything seems good up until Step 4. After choosing "Create new network..." the dialog doesn't look like what is shown above. I have 4 fields: (1) Wifi-adapter (2) Network Name (3) Wifi Security (4) Key

Comment: ... and I don't see any option to select my existing configured Hotspot there, only to create what I guess is a new ad-hoc network.

Comment: For 16.04LTS setting the mode as Hotspot was the key. However, there may be a set missing? On an Aspire F15 a network (up down arrows in top right corner) then WiFi network > Disconnect, disable wifi wait for a minute, enable wifi, then Create New Wi-fi Network. Otherwise devices could not connect to the Ubuntu hotspot.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Sorry 4 the late reply. But I was able to reproduce your issue when using more than one WiFi adapter. Does your machine have two of them? Or maybe a virtual one? I suggest you try either disabling one or create hotspot connection under the first one

Comment: @Underverse Are u using a development version of Ubuntu, like 17.04? I haven't tested on 17.04 yet. Or it could be a hardware specific issue.

Comment: @HEXcube 16.04LTS :-)

Comment: @HEXcube - indeed, I have one internal adapter but also a second one was connected via USB while I was attempting that. I don't have a choice of what adapter to use as I need to use the external one for receiving long-range signals.

Comment: @BeeOnRope - I have two wifi adapters (one is built in, one is a USB dongle) on my Ubuntu 17.04 laptop.  I'm seeing the same problem as you: in step 4 the "New Wi-Fi network" dialog doesn't give me the option to select the hotspot I configured.  Did you ever figure out how to make this work?

Comment: @adam - nope. Extra characters to meet limit.

Comment: IMPORTANT. WEP does not work for android phone. Change to WPA.

Answer (score 117):

**Whether your wireless card support Access Point mode.**

First thing to be done is perform the test whether your wireless card support going into wireless access point mode.  As told earlier following test is for mac80211 framework based driver.

Install `iw` & execute following

```
sudo aptitude install iw
iw list
```

Look for supported interface section, where it should be a entry called `AP` like below

```
Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * mesh point
```

If your driver doesn't shows this AP, It doesn't mean it can't create wireless hotspot. But those cards aren't in scope of this tutorial. For more tests follow [ubuntu documentation on master mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode).

The setup is divided in three sections,

1. Setup & host a wireless network
2. IP address setup
3. Internet sharing

**1.Setup and host a network**

- Software required: [hostapd [image: Install hostapd]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/hostapd) (install it)
- Press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksu gedit` & press <kbd>enter</kbd>. We are going to edit a lot of files.
- In gedit, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> & paste it in location box `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Paste the following code,

  ```
  interface=wlan0
  driver=nl80211
  ssid=test
  hw_mode=g
  channel=1
  macaddr_acl=0
  auth_algs=1
  ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
  wpa=3
  wpa_passphrase=1234567890
  wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  wpa_pairwise=TKIP
  rsn_pairwise=CCMP
  ```

**Please make sure there are no trailing white space and the end of the line! Hostapd is [very sensitive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403334/hostapd-gives-error-nl80211-register-action-command-failed-ret-19) to ending white spaces that are hard to troubleshoot!**

*Changes you need to do:*

1. Change `interface=wlan0` to your wireless card name. (If you have one wireless card it should be wlan0)
2. `ssid=test`. `test` is the name of your hosted network.
3. `wpa_passphrase=1234567890`, `1234567890` is the password of your network.

The configuration above creates a wpa & wpa2 enabled access point in `g` mode. A more detailed instruction to build configuration file can be found [here](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd)

Now start the `hostapd`. Edit the file `/etc/default/hostapd` and modify the line of DAEMON_CONF like this:

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

Then start the `hostapd` service using the following command,

`sudo service hostapd start`

It should start a wireless network. In your mobile device now you can see a wireless network and can authenticate.  But the device won't get IP address. Stop it with the command `sudo service hostapd stop`

> **If you get any error, possibly your card doesn't support `g` mode. Try with other >modes. [Guide](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd)**

**Part 2: Set up DHCP server for IP address management**

Install [isc-dhcp-server [image: Install isc-dhcp-server]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/isc-dhcp-server)

Edit the file `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` and set INTERFACES like this:

```
INTERFACES="wlan0"
```

In gedit, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, in location box paste `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`
Find (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) below lines and put **#** before it. It should look like after editing

```
# option definitions common to all supported networks…
#option domain-name “example.org”;
#option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;
```

Again comment out following lines too

```
#default-lease-time 600;
#max-lease-time 7200;
```

Add following lines at end

```
subnet 10.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 10.10.0.2 10.10.0.16;
        option domain-name-servers 8.8.4.4, 208.67.222.222;
        option routers 10.10.0.1;
}
```

*Range describe how long the address pool will be. you need to adjust subnet value also. This config can give IP up to 15 devices*

Again press <kbd>Cctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in gedit and paste following in location bar `/etc/network/interfaces`, Add below

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 10.10.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

`wlan0` is your wireless interface. Change it accordingly.

> Note: After reboot the wireless will be shown as not managed. So you
>   can't use any other wi-fi network. To get wireless with normal
>   behaviour, put # before those newly added line and execute `sudo start
>   networking`

now run

`sudo service isc-dhcp-server start`

`sudo service hostapd start`

At this point , your mobile device will see a network, authenticate it & after authentication it will get ip address something like `10.10.0.2`.

**Setup internet connection settings**

For Internet connection sharing we need `ip forwarding` and `ip masquerading`. 
Enable ip forwarding : execute

`echo 1| sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Now say you are using to a dial up/usb modem connection to connect to INTERNET. You need to get the logical interface name. For that execute `ifconfig` or `ip address`

For dialup/usb modem: it should be `ppp0`. If you want to share Ethernet connection you should use `ethX`where X is your ethernet device number. If you are connecting to internet through an android device with USB tethering, then the interface name should be `usb0`.

Now once you get the interface name execute
`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/16 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE`

**The `ppp0` in above command is the interface whose internet connection you are sharing over wireless.**

If you have edited upto `/etc/network/interfaces` you can use [this script](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/26252340/startServer.sh) to start the service. Edit it if you are not sharing `ppp0`. if you are using script and want to stop the server, use `sudo killall hostapd`

---

A blog that is mostly a summary of what has been described here: http://dashohoxha.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-setup-wifi-access-point-on-ubuntu.html

A script that tries to automate the steps described here: https://gist.github.com/dashohoxha/5767262

Please feel free to report or fix any bugs that you notice.

---

Great helps from :

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode
- http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd
- http://thenewbieblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/wifi-hotspot-setup-on-ubuntu/
- [How do I install and configure a DHCP server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140126/how-do-i-configure-a-dhcp-server)

Comment: I could connect to hotspot and authenticate. But I am not able to receive an IP. Could you help me out?

Comment: @neo have youcommented out the lines in config

Comment: I did. I actually tried the whole process twice, just to make sure I did not do it wrong the first time.

Comment: Neo is right. There is something definitely wrong with ubuntu. This has recently stopped working!

Comment: @Web-E This should be documented at Ubuntu community wiki for hostapd. May be a separate section under  [sharing Mobile Broadband](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SharingMobileBroadband)?

Comment: If only I had such knowledge. This is a life saver. Thanks

Comment: @ neo i faced the same problem. I just changed `dns=dnsmasq` to `#dns=dnsmasq` in `sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` after installing `ap-hotspot`. It fixed the problem.

Comment: Which Ubuntu versions does this support (the version of hostapd [ap-hotspot](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html) uses seems to no longer be available... :C )

Comment: i follwed all steps as suggested but it gives authenticatino problem when connecting from devices :-(, any help?

Comment: Do not forget to turn wpa-supplicant off:

`systemctl disable wpa_supplicant &&
systemctl stop wpa_supplicant`

Comment: @AlexanderVasiljev Why do we need to turn it off?
@Web-E Are the DNS values in your `dhcpd.conf` example made up? What values do I have to use in my own case?

Comment: @alonsos wpa_supplicant conflicts with hostapd in my case

Comment: @alonsos those were Google public dns & open dns ip address, you can use ip provided by your ISP

Comment: Tried this on raspberry PI, connected device had no internet.

Answer (score 33):

I too had the same problem. The best solution I could find is to use **ap-hotspot** for creating a hotspot of the ubuntu machine. It works fine for connecting to almost all android, windows phones, etc.

To install it:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

Next, to start the hotspot:

```
$ sudo ap-hotspot start
```

It asks you which adapter's internet you want to share, name of the network, password, etc. in an interactive manner.

To stop the hotspot :

```
$ sudo ap-hotspot stop
```

To configure it:

```
$ sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

If any problem, hope this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html) helps.

EDIT:

For now it seems there is some problem with Ubuntu 14.04, and as specified in the webupd8.org article linked, you have to downgrade hostapd:

64bit:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.ksu.edu.tw/FTP/Linux/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

32bit:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.ksu.edu.tw/FTP/Linux/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

Comment: Dude, that worked like a charm!

Comment: I followed the instructions on the previous answer and found that my wireless card was not supported for access point mode. But ap-hotspot still worked perfectly.  So my advise would be to just install ap-hotspot and see if it's working

Comment: It works for me if I stop network-manager with `sudo stop network-manager`  before starting ap-hotspot. Thanks!

Comment: You have to turn the wireless on the computer on first, but not connect it to anything - This works brilliantly :-)  -*But I will say that I could just use the default `Use as Hotpot` button in Fedora 19 (other half off dual boot)*

Comment: Didn't work for me. When I try connecting with my iPhone, it can connect and give a password successfully, but it never gets past that.

Comment: For both this answer and the one above, I will connect on my nexus10 at full signal for a bit, then drop out, state "authenticating" again, before finishing with "authentication problem". Disabling authentication just results in an endless loop.

Comment: This answer combined with the accepted one helped me do it. Thanks.

Comment: I get `Your wireless card does not support Access Point mode` even though it works on **Connectify** and **Virtualrouter** in windows

Comment: The script now seems to be deprecated.

Comment: I tried same steps but wifi is getting connected and disconnected continuously on my Lenovo thinkpad latop ( I created hostop in sony laptop). Also on android mobile wifi gets connected but shows limited connectivity and no internet connection. Please help.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Ubuntu 14.04. After `sudo ap-hotspot start` I see `Starting Wireless Hotspot...` line. But my Honor 9 Lite doesn't even see the connection. What it could be.

Answer (score 5):

Now, here's a method that's simple and will definitely do the job.

### **Install KDE Connection Editor**

Open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type the following commands, one after the other.

```
$ sudo apt-get install plasma-nm
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Now, you've just installed KDE Connection Editor.

Let's create a Wi-Fi Hotspot.

### **Create a Wi-Fi Hotspot (Access Point mode)**

#### 1.Now open the installed application by either,

1. Search(Alt+F2) for **kde-nm-connection-editor**( You'll it as soon
   as you start typing **kde**).

   **OR**
2. Open it manually from the Terminal.

   ```
   $ sudo kde-nm-connection-editor
   ```

#### 2.Now click **+ Add** and select **Wireless (shared)**

[image: Adding A new connection]

#### 3.Now, you'll see the below window.

[image: Connection setup tab]

**SSID**: Give a name for your new Hotspot

**Mode**: Select **Access Point**

**Cloned MAC address**: Click **Random** button to generate a random MAC address.

Everything else should be already set to fine.

#### 4.Now let's go to the **Wireless Security** tab.

[image: WPA Password tab]

Select **WAP & WPA2 Personal** and type your password.

Click **Ok**.

#### 5.Now your connection is ready.

[image: Ready]

Enjoy!

Comment: `kde-nm-connection-editor` became `kde5-nm-connection-editor` for me

Answer (score 2):

one of the easiest way i found is by using [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) by github user [oblique](https://github.com/oblique)

**Prerequisite:**

**1) hostapd**

```
sudo apt install hostapd
```

**steps :**

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
make install  (use sudo if you want to install it systemwide)
```

then two turn on hotspot

assuming u want to share internet from ethernet with interface name `eth0` using wifi interface `wlan0`, You can use following syntax:

```
create_ap -m nat wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

for more info and reference

https://github.com/oblique/create_ap

Answer (score 1):

@Web-E's answer was helpful, but also configures the computer as a router. I wanted *only* an Access Point, since I am already using my ISP's router.

I'm also running Ubuntu Server (18.04.2), so I couldn't use any GUI tools to set this up.

So, what I did was install and configure hostapd as described [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/180734/39662) and then simply bridged my Ethernet and Wi-Fi adapters. Here are the contents of my `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    # My Ethernet adapter
    enp1s0:
      # For some reason it seems I must specify at least something here.
      dhcp4: no
    # My Wi-Fi adapter
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        - enp1s0
        - wlp2s0
      # Using a static IP for this box.
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.45/24
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1]
```

Of course you will need to tweak your config file for your own needs. Just run `sudo netplan apply` afterwards to apply the configuration.