# How to forward an Internet connection to another network?

Tags: networking, network-manager, iptables, firestarter, ip-forward

Can somebody please make a short & sweet tutorial telling how to forward an Internet connection to different network interfaces in Ubuntu...?
This is the idea:

I'm using a **3G usb modem** to get Internet on my laptop ,which is:

> <kbd>ppp0</kbd>       **IP=10.225.174.70**

My Wifi device is:

> <kbd>wlan0</kbd> **MAC=78:e4:00:d4:3d:85**

These devices are determined from **ifconfig** command.

I want to share <kbd>ppp0</kbd>'s internet connection with <kbd>wlan0</kbd> device, so I can connect any other device to <kbd>wlan0</kbd> and browse internet from that device.

**Making a Hotspot using Network settings GUI doesn't do the trick because the other device won't receive Internet, it just connects to <kbd>wlan0</kbd>.**

I heard **iptables** can do this, but I'm totally confused by the alien commands seen online. I'm no expert in networking. Please compose a clear & simple answer using the above devices. This is a huge annoying problem for iPhone & tablet users came to Ubuntu from Windows.

Comment: I have already written a tut , hopefully this will solve your doubts. [This tut](http://askubuntu.com/q/180733/35775) is for setting up wi-fi access point. You can jump to `Setup internet connection settings` area

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sorry my driver doesn't show all the items in the AP list you have mentioned. 
My Device:
Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)

They say that I have to enable **Softmac Wireless Extentions** to enable **Master mode**. It's too complex... 
Isn't there a simple way? Some code, gui or something to redirect Internet..?
...and how to find what's my **ssid**?

Comment: See the tut was for creating wireless access point. You can create adhoc network and share it. See the  `Setup internet connection settings` - this section does the forwarding.  You can look [here](http://radu.cotescu.com/ubuntu-internet-connection-sharing-wireless/), a simpler step by step info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This is how I worked it out...

1. Create a new wireless network (aka hotspot) using the network manager.
2. Enable IP forwarding by executing the command below:

> echo 1| sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

3. Identify the device which connects your computer to Internet, by using **ifconfig** command. (My one is **ppp0**, because it has an IP address.)
4. Finally tell **iptables** to forward **ppp0**'s internet traffic to everywhere!

> sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/16 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE

Disconnect & reconnect the Wifi connection(Hotpsot) you made earlier.
Internet should be flowing to the wireless network now!
If you did it correctly, the output of **sudo iptables -L** should be similar to this:

> Chain **FORWARD** (policy ACCEPT)
> **target.....prot opt.....source....................destination**
> ACCEPT.....all  ---........  anywhere.............10.42.43.0/24.........state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
> ACCEPT.....all  ---........ 10.42.43.0/24......anywhere

An external guide is available [here.](http://www.howtoforge.com/internet-connection-sharing-masquerading-on-linux)

## Thanks to [web-E](https://askubuntu.com/users/35775/web-e)...!

Comment: worked like a charm. I just exchange ppp0 to eth1 (my usb modem) and the network to my local address. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you give in the notification area network select Create a wireless network follow the steps and ready your card happens to Access Point mode.

Note: Do not put that key shares usually happens when you put the key internet if connected verifies that the network-manager network settings you made in this mode ip shared with other pc.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, because I'm using a usb modem..

Comment: It doesn't matter if my ip gets shared.

Comment: no matter if you use usb modem. the ip which is the other must share the outgoing exit either lan or wlan