# Problem with AD-HOC wifi option

Tags: adhoc

I have internet access by ethernet and I want to use my notebook as a wifi point. I want to have internet access on various devices, too. 
I am trying to make my notebook as wifi access point by using ad-hoc option. 
I did everything like in this movie http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAvnh8TsFEU.
I suppose I did everthing ok, according the advices - I checked it a few times.

When configuration of ad-hoc network is finished, then my wifi detector going mad. Ubuntu tries to get access to ad-hoc network and it can but only four about 3 seconds. After that there is disconnected. Ubuntu tries to get access again and again.

In general it seems like this: ubuntu informational cloud on my desktop still shows information about connect and disconnet to ad-hoc network alternately. Without any break. Connected, disconnected, connected, disconnected.

Does anyone have any idea how can i fix it and create my ad-hoc network as stable thing?
Thanks

Comment: You can have a look here for step by step info → http://askubuntu.com/q/180733/35775

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to configure hostapd

I have configure following in hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf with WPA authentication options for wireless users

01 interface=wlan0

02 driver=nl80211

03 ssid=dontMessWithVincentValentine

04 hw_mode=g

05 channel=6

06 macaddr_acl=0

07 auth_algs=1

08 ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

09 wpa=3

10 wpa_passphrase=KeePGuessinG

11 wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

12 wpa_pairwise=TKIP

13 rsn_pairwise=CCMP

sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

**In graphical way u can try this link**

http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/