# Wifi Hostspot setup for Cable Modem Connection

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, dns, hot-spot

I have a broadband connection through my ISP (Hathway), using a cable modem. I wish to share the internet connection to my laptop, and the phone.

Refer to this configuration guide at [Wireless hotspot configuration and internet browsing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211744/12-10-wireless-hotspot-configuration-and-internet-browsing-question)

As of now, my laptop and phone are able to detect the WiFi hotspot and able to connect. But I am unable to browse / connect to the internet.

When I set up this connection, I see that it requires the DNS for the ISP, which I do not know. How do I set up `domain-name-servers` if I have a DHCP based IP address from the service provider.

Secondly, can the IP address of the hotspot be the DNS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option is making a shared conetion between your pc and laptops,

1. on pc that share conection (server) ckick on network icon and make a new conection put some pass type and pass
2. in client , find the new network and conect it, entering the same pass on server

, but this type somte timees is not compatible with androids phone,(have to download some app and root your phone... [here more info and pics](http://probandoubuntu.blogspot.com/2011/11/compartir-internet-en-ubuntu-una-forma.html)

other option is installing ap-hotspot, this way it's more compatible with androids phones, but some card networks isn't compatible, and then you have to enter it manually.

1. open a terminal and write `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`

   press enter

   sudo apt-get update

   press enter

   sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
2. now write `sudo ap-hotspot start`and if your card support AP mode you can configure network name and password