# Setting primary Internet connection and network on notebook

Tags: wireless, usb, internet

I have installed Ubuntu on a notebook that I have configured to connect to the Internet using an Iburst USB modem. This works 100% after a bit of configuring.

I now have a desktop PC that I have installed Ubuntu on, and would like to connect the two with a router. I bought a router with wifi, and would like to connect my notebook to the other computer using WiFi, while still keeping the Internet working with the USB modem.

The problem is that as soon as the WiFi connects, the Internet connection dies. Is there a way to force Ubuntu to get Internet access through the USB modem, but use WiFi to connect to the network?

I am pretty new to Ubuntu so any help would be appreciated.

I also have a Samsung galaxy tab that I would like to connect to the Internet through USB modem via the WiFi, so is there also a way to share that Internet connection with the other computers on the network?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can fix it using the Terminal: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Sharing may work with the Network Manager:
https://jeremy.visser.name/2009/03/simple-internet-connection-sharing-with-networkmanager/

greez, Tommy

Answer (score 0):

Basic networking rule says, you can't connect & use two different network simultaneously from a device by any means. The applications can not determine which interface to use to send packets.

What you can do, share the USB internet connection  over wi-fi, I mean, route the internet of usb to wireless adapter (by access point method).  Now your netbook becomes the server. You can connect your home computer, tab to this network. You will get access internet in all devices. In this case your router will become useless. (you can use router to further distribute your network but another hop will slow down the clients).

[Here is a guide](https://askubuntu.com/q/180733/35775) if you are interested.

and as far 2nd question `connect to the internet through usb modem via the wifi`, doesn't make any sense to me. What are you trying to .. clarify.

Update the question, I will update question accordingly.