# Is it possible to create Hotspot (Infrastructure) from wireless?

Tags: wireless, networking, wireless-access-point, ps3

I have 2 wireless cards, internal & usb wifi. I am connected to the internet with my USB Wifi which means that my internal wifi is idle all the time. I want to hook up my ps3 to the net as well, but ps3 doesn't see the internet signal also it is too far to drag an ethernet cable from the router to the ps3. Thus I want to share via my laptop. Ps3 is a bit of a retard and doesn't see Ad-Hoc, so I am gonna try to use ubuntu for this. I wonder is there a way to create infrastructured hotspot . I have successfully created adhoc hotspot between wired and wifi before in ubuntu, but now when I go to create hotspot with my idle wifi it creates it, but I cannot see it, I tried with my android, another pc and ps3, not there.

What would you suggest, thanks

Or should I rather bridge the connections somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup a wi-fi hotspot (access point mode)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode). Try it. If not working post wi-fi hardware details.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem at my house.  I could not get the ps3 to connect to the hotspot using Ubuntu.  Instead, I dragged my laptop down and connected it to the ps3 and shared my wifi connection to the ps3 over ethernet.  Would it be possible to move your laptop down by the ps3 when you want to play online?

Barring that, I would ask if you have tried to find your wireless internet connection manually (not Easy mode)?  I have found that Manual will still find your internet if you manually type in all of your information yourself.  If you need help with putting those settings in the ps3, I would be more than willing to help you over e-mail or on a ps3 forum of your choice.