# Atheros AR9285 with ath9k driver

Tags: wireless, atheros

I have ubuntu 12.10 64bit system, and my WiFi driver is kinda crazy. 
 
WiFi card in my notebook is AR9285 Atheros with ath9k driver,and after

> rfkill unblock all

command it is able to connect to wireless network, but when I create my own hotspot, I can't see that network on other device, anyway ubuntu is connected to it. There were some problems after installing ubuntu, I used

> rfkill list

command and wifi was soft and hard blocked.

Any idea what should I do? I feel like i tried almost everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I couldn't connect to hotspot with Android device, but this tutorial is great, and it works!
[Wifi HotSpot Access point mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode)