# Make a wifi repeater?

Tags: wireless

My house is wired for Ethernet but all the wires come to the basement which is where my dsl modem and my Netgear WNDR3700v3 wifi router is. I get practically no wifi signal upstairs but i have an Acer Revo upstairs running Ubuntu which is connected to my network with Ethernet and has wifi card built in (though I'm not using it). Is there a way I can make this into a repeater?

I've been reading up about it but there are some things I don't understand. I read that I need 2 wifi card and one needs have master mode. I don't understand what this means.

I also see that my WNDR3700 has an option to be a wireless base station and i can put in the mac address of 4 repeaters. Would I need to enable this to work with my revo as a repeater?

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/q/180733/35775) can help you to achieve this , but it will not create repeater, it will work as another router. :)

Comment: You don't want a wifi repeater as you have no wifi signal to repeat. What you want is to create a wifi Access Point.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try out this: 
[create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap)

Follow the documentation provided by the github repository itself. Make sure you have installed all dependencies.

**Installation**

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
make install
```

**Usage**

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Where `wlan0` and `eth0` refers to names of WiFi adapter and Ethernet controller of your PC used by OS. You can see those by using the command,

```
ip link show
```

And `MyAccessPoint` and `MyPassPhrase` refers to access point name and your password respectively.

Comment: Looks like this just creates a new WiFi network (which can also be done in Network Manager without any external tools). The OP wants to *extend* their existing network.