# Using a system with a Linux-based OS as bridge (for WIFI and ETH)

Tags: networking, wireless, network-bridge

**Context:**

I have an old working system with an Ubuntu version correctly running on it.

**The problem to solve:**

The wifi where I work does not reach every place in the office. The idea is to use this system as a bridge for extending the wifi range (please note that I am not even sure that the right word to use is *bridge*. If not, please correct me).

**Questions:**

1. is it possible to solve the problem with the solution I am proposing?
2. Should I use two different wifi antennas? (of course, I have more than one if necessary)
3. is there a standard procedure (or a ready-to-use OS) for that purpose? any advice or suggestions on how to do that?
4. additionally, can I connect this system to a switch in order to provide internet access to other systems connected via `eth`?

Sorry for this newbie question. I am quite new with networking issues.

Comment: quite possible that yes, it does. Let me test the procedure and I will give feedback. However it is not just repeating wifi. the question number 4 includes also `eth`.

Comment: @EliahKagan, I think it does not answer to the last part of the question (namely question number 4). Do you agree? updating the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called WiFi repeater, usually routers are used for this, but seems it's possible with Linux machine. Look at these answers, hope it will be helpful:

1. [Make a wifi repeater?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236401/make-a-wifi-repeater)
2. [WiFi repeater with a single WiFi adapter in Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340799/wifi-repeater-with-a-single-wifi-adapter-in-debian) (also applies to Ubuntu)

As for your questions:

1. According to links above, it seems to be possible.
2. Antennas may improve the signal, but also it may cause interference. If you have 5 GHz WiFi adapter, maybe it will be better to receive 2.4 GHz signal and translate 5 GHz or vice versa.
3. Looks like it's enough just to clone repo and build an application. This function enabled by default in some routers, but as I know, it's impossible to install such firmware on regular machine
4. If you mean to receive internet connections to your repeater and share internet from it both by wifi and ethernet, than yes, just create a *Shared to other computers* connection (It's called so on Ubuntu) and it should work, because you will have internet on your repeater.

   If you can share internet to repeater over ethernet, it's even easier, you'll not have any issues with interference and connection will be stable, all you need than is just set up a hotspot. (Ubuntu can do it out of the box, see [Create a wireless hotspot](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html.en).)

Comment: and what about the eth connection? :) if you write down a more complete answer I will vote up. For now, I am going to read carefully the question/answer suggested. However, I think the policies of the StackExchange does not admit just a link as answer, moderators will vote down and will suggest editing question :)

Comment: Well, I can repeat one of that questions, but I don't think it's fare :) actually, your question is very similar to the first link in my answer, but I can't mark it as a duplicate because it's not the same and because I don't have this privilege :) But I'll try to improve my answer

Comment: I have just voted up because thanks to your suggestion I partially solved my problem :) question number 4 is not. However, I insist to push you to writing something more in the answer to be accepted. It should not be copy-paste but re-elaborating the answer (and citing the reference). Do you agree that this is fare? :)