# Software to _easily_ create Hotspot

Tags: wireless, internet-connection, hot-spot

At [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode/180734#180734) there is a tricky and not always working solution to activate a wifi-hotspot using wifi.

Does someone know any program (like Connectify for Windows) that does this? I understand this question is widely present in all ubuntu websites but I hope some good guy that knows the answer would like to answer us :)

The matter is **create a wifi hotspot using the same wireless device connected to wifi**. In windows Connectify and other software do this smoothly.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/977645/349837) might help, or [this with gnome shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/439530/349837).