# How to create hotspot without internet connection?

Tags: wireless, 17.10, hot-spot

I am using XUbuntu 17.10 and i have created a wifi hotspot, the problem is i want to use the hotspot for samba and other things that don't require an internet connection. how do i create a wifi hotspot that **doesn't** share my internet connection? is this even possible?

Comment: How are you connecting the host computer(the machine which broadcasts the hotspot) to the internet? Ethernet?

Comment: I am using a Huawei 3G Modem @Yaksha, it is connected through a USB Port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to use [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap). From their site:

> create_ap is a tool that helps you create an open, or encrypted AP at any channel, hide your SSID, disable communication between clients (client isolation), IEEE 802.11n & 802.11ac support, Internet sharing methods: NATed or Bridged or None (no Internet sharing)

For your case you want to create an AP with the linux pc without sharing the internet from your dongle to clients, but can do other Lan stuff, like file sharing.

Your wifi card needs to support creating AP

1. Install some packages:

   ```
   sudo apt install util-linux bash procps hostapd iproute2 iw haveged net-tools dnsmasq iptables
   ```
2. Get the `create_ap` package. From the terminal do

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
   cd create_ap
   sudo make install
   ```
3. After installation, check the name of your modem and wifi card with `ifconfig` (deprecated) or:

   ```
   iwconfig
   ```

   the wifi card usually is `wlan0` or `wlp2s0` and usb modem is `eth0`. yours might be different
4. Now start hotspot from your linux without internet:

   ```
   sudo create_ap -n wlp2s0 MyAccessPoint
   ```

You can then connect clients. Your internet would not be shared but you can do samba and other things without internet

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that will create Hotspot but **not** share the `Ethernet` Internet with the `WiFi` devices. You will have to change the network interface name according to your system.

Type `ip link` to find them. Also, make sure you have installed `dnsmasq` and `hostapd`.

```
sudo apt-get install ifconfig dnsmasq hostapd
```

Before running the script you will have to stop any *Network Management Tool* which is controlling `WiFi`.

**eth-to-wifi-route.sh**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Share Eth with WiFi Hotspot
#
# This script is created to work with Raspbian Stretch
# but it can be used with most of the distributions
# by making few changes. 
#
# Make sure you have already installed `dnsmasq` and `hostapd`
# Please modify the variables according to your need
# Don't forget to change the name of network interface
# Check them with `ifconfig`

ip_address="192.168.2.1"
netmask="255.255.255.0"
dhcp_range_start="192.168.2.2"
dhcp_range_end="192.168.2.100"
dhcp_time="12h"
eth="eth0" # replace it with Huawei 3G Modem interface
wlan="wlan0"
ssid="Arpit-Raspberry"
psk="arpit1997"

sudo rfkill unblock wlan &> /dev/null
sleep 2

#sudo iptables -F
#sudo iptables -t nat -F
#sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $eth -j MASQUERADE  
#sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $eth -o $wlan -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
#sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i $wlan -o $eth -j ACCEPT 

#sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"

sudo ifconfig $wlan $ip_address netmask $netmask

sudo ip route del 0/0 dev $wlan &> /dev/null
a=`route | awk "/${eth}/"'{print $5+1;exit}'`
sudo route add -net default gw $ip_address netmask 0.0.0.0 dev $wlan metric $a

echo -e "interface=$wlan \n\
bind-interfaces \n\
server=8.8.8.8 \n\
domain-needed \n\
bogus-priv \n\
dhcp-range=$dhcp_range_start,$dhcp_range_end,$dhcp_time" > /etc/dnsmasq.conf

sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq

echo -e "interface=$wlan\n\
driver=nl80211\n\
ssid=$ssid\n\
hw_mode=g\n\
ieee80211n=1\n\
wmm_enabled=1\n\
macaddr_acl=0\n\
auth_algs=1\n\
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0\n\
wpa=2\n\
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n\
wpa_passphrase=$psk\n\
rsn_pairwise=CCMP" > /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

sudo systemctl restart hostapd
sudo systemctl status hostapd &> /dev/null
if [ "$?" != 0 ];then
    echo "Some Network Management tool is running, which is stopping" 
    echo "hostapd to be configured."
    echo "Please stop that and again run the script."
fi
```

I have commented the `iptable` and `packet forwarding` commands. If anytime you need to give internet to the devices just uncomment them.

**Run the script**

```
sudo bash eth-to-wifi-route.sh
```

Source: [eth-to-wifi-route.sh](https://github.com/arpitjindal97/raspbian-recipes/blob/master/eth-to-wifi-route.sh)