# Why Ubuntu disconnects from wifi when turning on hotspot and how to solve this problem?

Tags: wireless, hot-spot, connection-sharing

[image]

Why Ubuntu disconnects from Wi-Fi when turning on hotspot and how to solve this problem??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a WiFi hotspot sharing wireless internet connection (single adapter)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is quite simple.

You can use your WiFi adapter as a hotspot, or you can use it as a client to connect to another network.

You can't do both at the same time.

Comment: It can't be done from Network Manager but this should work https://askubuntu.com/questions/970445/how-to-create-hotspot-without-internet-connection

Comment: I have used create_ap to use one wifi device to connect to a AP and use it as a hotspot at the same time

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/318973/how-do-i-create-a-wifi-hotspot-sharing-wireless-internet-connection-single-adap  That is the one

Comment: That's a good find and could be marked as a duplicate of this question.  It does seem that in order to pull this off, that you either need two network interfaces or one of a handful of network adapters that have the capability.