# Created Hotspot not found using other devices

Tags: hot-spot

I have Ubuntu 12.10 on my desktop machine and have a wireless capability on it using D-Link DWA-121 .
The Desktop machine have Ethernet connection.
When creating a wireless hotspot by doing the following:

Open All Settings --> Network --> Wireless --> Use as Hotspot

[image: network dialog]

I can't see the network from other machines or phones.
any hints?

Comment: try - http://tumutanzi.com/archives/8195.

Comment: Thanks @Web-E Tried all that now and still now detected, it's created but can't be seen from other machines

Comment: I am now able to create the hotspot using this post [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode/180734#180734) but when connecting it always fail in the connection, so the wireless hotspot is visible but i am unable to access it

Comment: may be your card doesn't support `g` mode. Try building a hostapd file on your own using `a` / `b` or `n` mode. http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd