# Cannot create wireless AP

Tags: 12.10, wireless, broadcom, hostapd, hostap

I've tried to create AP using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode) and tried to solve my problem

```
$ iw list
nl80211 not found.
```

with [this](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd), but I still get error when I start `make`

```
~/hostapd-2.0/hostapd$ make
../src/drivers/driver_nl80211.c:19:31: fatal error: netlink/genl/genl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [../src/drivers/driver_nl80211.o] Error 1
```

Any ideas?

I have a Broadcom wireless card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [link you posted](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd) it says:

```
if this fails with errors like:

driver_nl80211.c:21:31: warning: netlink/genl/genl.h: No such file or directory
driver_nl80211.c:22:33: warning: netlink/genl/family.h: No such file or directory
driver_nl80211.c:23:31: warning: netlink/genl/ctrl.h: No such file or directory
driver_nl80211.c:24:25: warning: netlink/msg.h: No such file or directory
driver_nl80211.c:25:26: warning: netlink/attr.h: No such file or directory



you need to install/update libnl-1.0pre8 (or later). If all goes well and the 
compilation finishes, try the minimal hostapd again, see the section Using your
distributions hostapd above for that.
```

So...

```
sudo apt-get install libnl1 libnl-dev
```

then run the build

---

I skimmed through this and I don't think your card will work for this

to be sure, run this:

```
lspci | grep -i network
```

If you have a Broadcom 43.... card this route won't work. [See this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode#Broadcom_43xx_cards_.28bcm43xx.ko.29)

Comment: THX, I didn't know what lib files exactly should I install. `make` now works, however I still cannot create hotspot, I got `~/hostap/hostapd$ ./hostapd ./hostapd-minimal.conf
Configuration file: ./hostapd-minimal.conf
nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found
Failed to initialize driver 'nl80211'`

Comment: what is your reason for compiling this yourself?

Comment: I have hostapd installed as you said, but it doesn't work, so I tried the option in the second link I posted. with hostapd installed via `apt-get` I get `$ hostapd ./hostapd-minimal.conf
Configuration file: ./hostapd-minimal.conf
nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found
Failed to initialize driver 'nl80211'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
`