# Ubuntu Network Manger keep creating Ad-Hoc Hotspot. No infrastructure. A bug?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, android, adhoc, hot-spot

I'd like to share my Ubuntu wired connection with a Wifi android tablet. To do that I could use the "Use as Hotspot..." function in System Settings->Network. As I can understand, android has issues with ad-hoc Hotspot function of the Network Manager, which is the default option in Hotspot.
Problem is that when I change from Ad-Hoc to Infrastructure in the "options" the change is not immediate. If I stop and restart the Hotspot, a brand new config is created, even a new password, but always as Ad-Hoc. For every attempt I can see in the Network Connections a new hotspot config but I can't find a way to "reuse" the one I setup with Infrastructure option.
BTW, my Wifi card can work as AP because hostapd works fine.

Answer (score 0):

this is "well-known" state that Ubuntu is not capable creating hotspot as Infrastructure. I'm just tried it myself.

It seems that there is a solution with "hostapd" daemon. Please check the following manual:

[GUIDE] Making infrastructure wifi hotspot on ubuntu 12.04/12.10

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2009381

Unfortunately, for me, I've got unsupported Wifi driver. Hopefully, it will help at least you. :-|

Please see also: [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode)