# How to share a internet connection using wireless to a galaxy note/2?

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

Currently I am using Tata Photon+ usb modem  as my internet source. I need to share the network from my laptop to my Samsung Galaxy note 2 and samsung galaxy note. I tried searching many posts but it seems they all work for wired internet connection. Please I am new to Ubuntu so please provide me the steps in details how to get this working.

Comment: possible duplicate, [Ubuntu Network Manger keep creating Ad-Hoc Hotspot. No infrastructure. A bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/277056/ubuntu-network-manger-keep-creating-ad-hoc-hotspot-no-infrastructure-a-bug)

Comment: @ShaharilAhmad not sure it is a duplicated of that question.

Comment: @Shaharil -- This will not work in my case. I am using USB dongle and that adhoc wireless network trick works with wired internet connection but unfortunately not with usb modem.

Comment: Also if you have any solution please provide that in detail as I am quiet new with these kind of stuffs.

Comment: this might help, [How To Set Up A Wireless Hotspot (Access Point Mode) That Supports Android In Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html)

Comment: This is not working for me, have you tried creating a network while using tata photon+ modem. What I want to do is use tata photon+ for accessing internet and then setup a wireless connection so that I can access internet over my android.