# Hostapd wifi AP

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, dhcp, hostapd

I am trying to start wifi AP with hostapd, followed carefully all of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode) instructions. For now, from my phone, i see network, i connect to it, but it stucks at receiving ip address and then just terminates connection.

hostapd-minimal.conf:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=test
hw_mode=g
channel=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=88888888
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

dhcpd.conf:

```
ddns-update-style none;

# option definitions common to all supported networks...
#option domain-name "example.org";
#option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

#default-lease-time 600;
#max-lease-time 7200;

log-facility local7;

subnet 10.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 10.10.0.2 10.10.0.16;
        option domain-name-servers 8.8.4.4, 208.67.222.222;
        option routers 10.10.0.1;
}
```

interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 10.10.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I launch it with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /bin/bash -c "
start isc-dhcp-server
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
hostapd $HOME/hostapd-minimal.conf -B
"
```

Tried to run hostapt with -d debug option and all output is here - http://pastebin.com/GCUPiyRT

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, all settings were correct, all worked after update of ics-dhcp-server package

Comment: I'll return the bounty to you - this is clearly a "too localized" issue that probably will not help others in the future.