# Impossible to turn Inspirion 1545 into Access Point?

Tags: drivers, inspiron, wireless-access-point

My wireless card worked out of the box, but now I want to turn the maschine into an access point so I followed these guides

- [Setting up a Wifi Adapter to support "master mode"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode)
- [How to setup a wi-fi hotspot (access point mode)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode)

Unfortunately, `iwconfig eth1 mode master` returns `Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) : SET failed on device eth1 ; Invalid argument.`
and according to `iw list` supported interface modes are `IBSS` and `managed`.

Strangely using Windows' hosted network works fine.

My Network Controller is `Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)`.

Answer (score 1):

IBSS means ad-hoc, that is computer-to-computer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_Basic_Service_Set

```
With 802.11, one can alternatively set up an ad-hoc network of client
devices without a controlling access point; the result is called an
IBSS (independent BSS).
```

Therefore, your hardware and driver combination supports master mode; that is computer-to-access point as well as ad-hoc mode; that is, computer-to-computer. Master mode is evidently unsupported.

Comment: unfortunately ad-hoc mode will not work for me because I want use an old android device and a handheld that won't support ad-hoc connections. But are you saying that I should just follow the instructions in the guides?

Comment: installing the open source driver (http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Ubuntu.2FDebian) helped now `iw list` shows AP