# How to share internet connection from USB Wireless Broadband using wifi?

Tags: wireless, internet, hot-spot

Please I need help.

Objective: Be able to create a Wifi-Hotspot on my laptop[Dell Inspiron 5520 64-bit with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS] and share the internet connection being supplied via my USB Internet Wireless Broadband Dongle [ZTE Reliance Netconnect] with my android smartphone and other laptops at home.

Progress so far:
1. I am able to use my dongle conveniently after configuring it using wvdial.

1. I tried setting up an "New Wireless Network" ad-hoc but the sharing did not work. In fact my phone wasn't able to connect to this network.
2. I saw other Similar Posts on AskUbuntu and most of them are based on sharing a "Wired" Connection which doesn't help my case. In fact, one similar question was flagged duplicate even though the person had clearly mentioned he needs an answer for "Wireless" connection such as myself.
3. when I use "iwconfig" I get the following, is this correct?

   $ iwconfig
   ppp0      no wireless extensions.

   eth0      no wireless extensions.

   eth2      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any
             Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated
             Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
             Power Management:off

   lo        no wireless extensions.

How can I achieve this? Please someone guide me step-by-step. Thanks :)

Comment: check this.. [How to setup a wi-fi hotspot (access point mode)?](http://askubuntu.com/q/180733)

Answer (score 1):

To re-broadcasting your internet via wireless you should have a Wireless ethernet card that supports [Master  Mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode).

Suggest you check with Dell Support (you must do this for they will ask for your Product Code) to see if the wireless card included with your Dell supports Master Mode. Their chat is at http://www.dell.com/learn/campaigns/chat-splitter-us

[This](https://askubuntu.com/q/180733) askubuntu question cover both wired and mobile broadband, but from comments it seems to be outdated. [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SharingMobileBroadband) describes how to configure mobile broadband (via a USB dongle or other ppp based) then re-broadcasting this via wireless or wired ethernet.