# How to set my Broadcom BCM4313 wireless card into AP mode?

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, hostapd

I've been trying to create an Access Point hotspot using `hostapd`, but I get an error message saying that my card doesn't support AP mode. I tried `sudo iwconfig eth1 mode master` and I get the following error:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device eth1 ; Invalid argument.
```

How do I get Ubuntu to recognize the card's AP mode function? Because it clearly supports Access Point mode as it works perfectly with Connectify on Windows.

As per the output of `lspci | grep Wireless`, my card is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: I guess the driver might not support AP mode.

Answer (score 2):

## Access Point mode Hotspot on BCM4313

**BCM4313** can operate on AP mode using `brcmsmac` driver, starting from 3.10 linux kernel onwards. For a very long time, **BCM4313** didn't have AP mode support under any linux driver. But now, you got lucky, coz both AdHoc(IBSS) and AP mode have been implemented for `brcmsmac`. So, for making AP mode work for BCM4313, you need a linux kernel newer than 3.10. Use **Ubuntu 12.04.5LTS**, **Ubuntu 14.04LTS** or a newer release. If you're using a **Ubuntu 12.04LTS** version older than 12.04.5, install the package  [linux-generic-lts-trusty](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/linux-generic-lts-trusty) [image]. 
For more details about upgrading 12.04LTS's kernel, [visit this link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/ubuntu-12-04-4-released-new-kernel).
Once you have a suitable kernel, make sure you are not running other Broadcom drivers like `bcmwl-kernel-source`,`b43`,etc. If yes, uninstall them. No need to explicitly install `brcmsmac`, as it is already a preinstalled module in the linux kernel. Now, create Access Point hotspot according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode/439530#439530). This is a custom `hostapd` configuration I use with **BCM4313** wireless card :

```
#####Basic Settings########################
#sets the wifi interface to use, is wlan0 in most cases
interface=wlan0
#driver to use, nl80211 works in most cases
driver=nl80211
#Access Point name
#Replace it with ssid=<YourHotspotName>
ssid=HEXspot

#####Channel and Mode Settings#############
# Operation mode (a = IEEE 802.11a, b = IEEE 802.11b, g = IEEE 802.11g,
# ad = IEEE 802.11ad (60 GHz); a/g options are used with IEEE 802.11n, too, to
# specify band)
# Default: IEEE 802.11b
hw_mode=g
# WiFi Channel:
channel=11

##### IEEE 802.11n related configuration ##
#WMM needs to be enabled for full HT functionality
wmm_enabled=1
# ieee80211n: Whether IEEE 802.11n (HT) is enabled
# 0 = disabled (default)
# 1 = enabled
# Note: You will also need to enable WMM for full HT functionality.
ieee80211n=1
# ht_capab: HT capabilities (list of flags)
# LDPC coding capability: [LDPC] = supported
# Supported channel width set: [HT40-] = both 20 MHz and 40 MHz with secondary
#   channel below the primary channel; [HT40+] = both 20 MHz and 40 MHz
#   with secondary channel below the primary channel
#   (20 MHz only if neither is set)
#   Note: There are limits on which channels can be used with HT40- and
#   HT40+. Following table shows the channels that may be available for
#   HT40- and HT40+ use per IEEE 802.11n Annex J:
#   freq        HT40-       HT40+
#   2.4 GHz     5-13        1-7 (1-9 in Europe/Japan)
#   5 GHz       40,48,56,64 36,44,52,60
#   (depending on the location, not all of these channels may be available
#   for use)
#   Please note that 40 MHz channels may switch their primary and secondary
#   channels if needed or creation of 40 MHz channel maybe rejected based
#   on overlapping BSSes. These changes are done automatically when hostapd
#   is setting up the 40 MHz channel.
# Spatial Multiplexing (SM) Power Save: [SMPS-STATIC] or [SMPS-DYNAMIC]
#   (SMPS disabled if neither is set)
# HT-greenfield: [GF] (disabled if not set)
# Short GI for 20 MHz: [SHORT-GI-20] (disabled if not set)
# Short GI for 40 MHz: [SHORT-GI-40] (disabled if not set)
# Tx STBC: [TX-STBC] (disabled if not set)
# Rx STBC: [RX-STBC1] (one spatial stream), [RX-STBC12] (one or two spatial
#   streams), or [RX-STBC123] (one, two, or three spatial streams); Rx STBC
#   disabled if none of these set
# HT-delayed Block Ack: [DELAYED-BA] (disabled if not set)
# Maximum A-MSDU length: [MAX-AMSDU-7935] for 7935 octets (3839 octets if not
#   set)
# DSSS/CCK Mode in 40 MHz: [DSSS_CCK-40] = allowed (not allowed if not set)
# PSMP support: [PSMP] (disabled if not set)
# L-SIG TXOP protection support: [LSIG-TXOP-PROT] (disabled if not set)
ht_capab=[HT40][GF][SHORT-GI-40][SHORT-GI-20]
# Require stations to support HT PHY (reject association if they do not)
require_ht=1

#####Security and Authentication###########
#macaddr_acl sets options for mac address filtering. 0 means "accept unless in deny list"
macaddr_acl=0
#Sets authentication algorithm
#1 - only open system authentication
#2 - both open system authentication and shared key authentication
auth_algs=1
#setting ignore_broadcast_ssid to 1 will disable the broadcasting of ssid
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

#####Sets WPA and WPA2 authentication######
#wpa option sets which wpa implementation to use
#1 - wpa only
#2 - wpa2 only
#3 - both
wpa=2
#sets WPA Password required by the clients to authenticate themselves on the network
#Replace it with wpa_passphrase=<Password you wish to use>
wpa_passphrase=anything
#sets wpa key management
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
#sets encryption used by WPA2
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

This configuration enables `hostapd` to start **802.11n** mode Access Point for BCM4313. You may use this instead of the generic g-mode configuration described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode/180734#180734).