# How to access hostspot in mobile phone?

Tags: 13.10, android, hot-spot, wifi-direct

Is it possible to access hotspot in mobile phone or not?
After I start Hotspot from my laptop,the hotspot id is shown in the mobile while I refresh for the available wifi's but it never gets connected.

"I am a Ubuntu13.10 user. I use Samsung Galaxy Note"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)

Answer (score 1):

To set up a simple wifi hotpsot for Android and other phones, you can use `ap-hotspot` as detailed [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html).

Basically, install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm this - then run these to actually install it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

<sup>[Use `ppa`'s at your own not-very-high risk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo) - note you need to add the PPA and run the update command before you are able to install it.</sup>
Start it with:

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
```

You can also stop it:

```
sudo ap-hotspot stop
```

and configure it:

```
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

Android does not seem to support the hotspot created in Ubuntu - <sub><rant>even though I have never had this trouble with [another Linux operating system](https://getfedora.org/)</rant></sub> . Ubuntu 14.04 apparently needs a special fix as well.

> #### For Ubuntu 14.04:
>
> also the `hostapd` version in Ubuntu 14.04 is buggy and doesn't
>   work properly. To get AP-Hotspot to work with hostapd in Ubuntu 14.04,
>   you need to downgrade hostapd and use apt to hold the package so it's
>   not upgraded (thanks to spupuz for the tip!). To do this, use the
>   following commands:
>
> **64bit:**
>
> ```
> cd /tmp
> wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
> sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
> sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
> ```
>
> **32bit:**
>
> ```
> cd /tmp
> wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
> sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
> sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
> ```

Comment: #Wilf it says ap-hotspot command not found Also I tried to install ap-hotspot but it says unable to locate package ap-hotspot

Comment: You have to add the `ppa` - it is a [WebUd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8), so should be fine.Tthe ppa just allows access to extra packages, including the `ap-hotspot` one.

Comment: @Wilf - Still doesn't work wid ubuntu 15.04

Comment: @LaxmikantGurnalkar - I know it doesn't really work with 14.10+ (and that fix is needed for 14.04) - I think there are alternatives except I can't remember what they are currently (need one myself anyway). You can try [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot).

Comment: @Wilf - Ok, Thanks for the suggestion, Will go through it.