# Create Wi-Fi hotspot in Lubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, 15.04, ap-hotspot

I'm new to the OS and chose this community to find some help on my problems. I have Lubuntu based on version 15.04; I'm very satisfied, though it's more complicated than windows, but faster and safer. Now I want some help with creating a wifi hotspot on my laptop using incoming connection from wired ethernet. I have read and watched many tutorials but neither helped me. The problem is that I can't install ap-hotspot from Terminal, as it says "Unable to locate package ap-hotspot". Is there any other way to do this? I'm using Dell Inpiron B120 old laptop with 512mb ram. Adapter is Broadcom 4318 and all drivers and firmware are installed. I don't know if any further information is needed.

Answer (score 3):

`ap-hotspot` is pretty outdated as the developer has stopped working on it for quite some time now. I suggest using `create_ap` as an alternative. To install, type the following in terminal.

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap 
make install
```

Complete details on installation and use is found [here](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap).

Comment: I typed the command in terminal several times, and after that there was created folder named create_ap, but the program isn't installed and so doesn't work. Now every time I type the command, I receive this: luka7@PC7:~$ git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
fatal: destination path 'create_ap' already exists and is not an empty directory.
luka7@PC7:~$ cd create_ap 
luka7@PC7:~/create_ap$ make install 
The program 'make' can be found in the following packages:
 * make
 * make-guile
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
luka7@PC7:~/create_ap$

Comment: @luka7 you need to install `make` and other utilities needed to compile it by installing the `build-essential` package. You will probably also need to install the dependencies it list [here](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap#dependencies). If the `make install` fails due to permissions, you can try `sudo make install` - you can also use [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) with `sudo checkinstall` instead of make install, it makes it easier to remove the package afters it is installed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8/+packages) currently has a version of `ap-hotspot` available for 15.04, however you should be able to install it by downloading the deb file from [here](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8/+packages?field.name_filter=ap-hotspot&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=) for another Ubuntu version (the below instructions use 14.10's) and installing it:

```
wget "https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8/+files/ap-hotspot_0.3-1%7Ewebupd8%7E4_all.deb"
sudo gdebi ap-hotspot_0.3-1~webupd8~4_all.deb
```

<sup>If at a later date the above links/commands don't work, the package may have been updated so you will need to download and install the latest version from [here](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8/+packages?field.name_filter=ap-hotspot&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=) manually.</sup>

You can also download the file in a web browser from [here](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8/+sourcepub/4564862/+listing-archive-extra) and install it using Software Center.

Note this still may not work, as the script was designed for 13.10 so it probably needs a few tweaks to work with 15.04 and other versions.

You can then start it with:

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
```

You can also stop it:

```
sudo ap-hotspot stop
```

and configure it:

```
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

**See also:**

- Instructions for 12.04, 12.10, 13.10, 14.04 (including 'patch') & 14.10 can be found in my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/422541/178596), based on the original [WebUp8 article](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html).

Comment: Sorry for late response, I tried using your method and successfully installed ap-hotspot, but when I try to start it using terminal, it says starting wifi hotspot and nothing changes after that. I don't know may be it's caused of that I'm using 15.04 version. If you know some solution please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help everyone, but now I have already found the solution on Youtube. I used in terminal this command:"kde5-nm-connection-editor" and opened KDE connection editor and so I managed to create new Wi-Fi hotspot and it works very well.

Comment: For future readers, here is the link to do it http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/

Answer (score 0):

I have this old script that helped me to make a WiFi-Hotspot from my ethernet connection. It might not work but its worth a try.

***Code:***

```
#!/bin/bash
### Setup a wifi Access Point on Ubuntu 12.04 (or its derivatives).

### make sure that this script is executed from root
if [ $(whoami) != 'root' ]
then
    echo "
This script should be executed as root or with sudo:
    sudo $0
"
    exit 1
fi

##############################################################
## Check whether the wireless card supports Access Point mode
##############################################################

### make sure that iw is installed
apt-get -y install iw

### check that AP is supported
supports_access_point=$(iw list | sed -n -e '/* AP$/p')
if [ "$supports_access_point" = '' ]
then
    echo "AP is not supported by the driver of the wireless card."
    echo "This script does not work for this driver."
    exit 1
fi

##############################################################
##  Setup and host a network
##############################################################

### install hostapd
apt-get -y install hostapd

### it should not start automatically on boot
update-rc.d hostapd disable

### get ssid and password
ssid=$(hostname --short)
read -p "The name of your hosted network (SSID) [$ssid]: " input
ssid=${input:-$ssid}
password='1234567890'
read -p "The password of your hosted network [$password]: " input
password=${input:-$password}

### get wifi interface
rfkill unblock wifi   # enable wifi in case it is somehow disabled (thanks to Darrin Wolf for this tip)
wifi_interface=$(lshw -quiet -c network | sed -n -e '/Wireless interface/,+12 p' | sed -n -e '/logical name:/p' | cut -d: -f2 | sed -e 's/ //g')

### create /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
cat <<EOF > /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
interface=$wifi_interface
driver=nl80211
ssid=$ssid
hw_mode=g
channel=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=$password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
EOF

### modify /etc/default/hostapd
cp -n /etc/default/hostapd{,.bak}
sed -i /etc/default/hostapd \
    -e '/DAEMON_CONF=/c DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"'

################################################
## Set up DHCP server for IP address management
################################################

### make sure that the DHCP server is installed
apt-get -y install isc-dhcp-server

### it should not start automatically on boot
update-rc.d isc-dhcp-server disable

### set the INTERFACES on /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
cp -n /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server{,.bak}
sed -i /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server \
    -e "/INTERFACES=/c INTERFACES=\"$wifi_interface\""

### modify /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
cp -n /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf{,.bak}
sed -i /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf \
    -e 's/^option domain-name/#option domain-name/' \
    -e 's/^option domain-name-servers/#option domain-name-servers/' \
    -e 's/^default-lease-time/#default-lease-time/' \
    -e 's/^max-lease-time/#max-lease-time/'

sed -i /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf \
    -e '/subnet 10.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0/,+4 d'
cat <<EOF >> /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
subnet 10.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 10.10.0.2 10.10.0.16;
        option domain-name-servers 8.8.4.4, 208.67.222.222;
        option routers 10.10.0.1;
}
EOF

#################################################
## Create a startup script
#################################################

cat <<EOF > /etc/init.d/wifi_access_point
#!/bin/bash

ext_interface=\$(ip route | grep default | cut -d' ' -f5)

function stop_wifi_ap {
    ### stop services dhcpd and hostapd
    service isc-dhcp-server stop
    service hostapd stop

    ### disable IP forwarding
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/16 -o \$ext_interface -j MASQUERADE 2>/dev/null

    ### remove the static IP from the wifi interface
    if grep -q 'auto $wifi_interface' /etc/network/interfaces
    then
        sed -i /etc/network/interfaces -e '/auto $wifi_interface/,\$ d'
        sed -i /etc/network/interfaces -e '\$ d'
    fi

    ### restart network manager to takeover wifi management
    service network-manager restart
}

function start_wifi_ap {
    stop_wifi_ap
    sleep 3

    ### see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1289047/comments/8
    nmcli nm wifi off
    rfkill unblock wlan

    ### give a static IP to the wifi interface
    ip link set dev $wifi_interface up
    ip address add 10.10.0.1/24 dev $wifi_interface

    ### protect the static IP from network-manger restart
    echo >> /etc/network/interfaces
    echo 'auto $wifi_interface' >> /etc/network/interfaces
    echo 'iface $wifi_interface' inet static >> /etc/network/interfaces
    echo 'address 10.10.0.1' >> /etc/network/interfaces
    echo 'netmask 255.255.255.0' >> /etc/network/interfaces

    ### enable IP forwarding
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/16 -o \$ext_interface -j MASQUERADE

    ### start services dhcpd and hostapd
    service hostapd start
    service isc-dhcp-server start
}

### start/stop wifi access point
case "\$1" in
    start) start_wifi_ap ;;
    stop)  stop_wifi_ap  ;;
esac
EOF

chmod +x /etc/init.d/wifi_access_point

### make sure that it is stopped on boot
sed -i /etc/rc.local \
    -e '/service wifi_access_point stop/ d'
sed -i /etc/rc.local \
    -e '/^exit/ i service wifi_access_point stop'


### display usage message
echo "
======================================

Wifi Access Point installed.

You can start and stop it with:
    service wifi_access_point start
    service wifi_access_point stop

"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a good solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Lubuntu/comments/2h13pr/how_to_setup_an_hotspot_in_lubuntu/). The additional step I had to do was:

- Explicitly connect to the Lubuntu hotspot wifi connection from the Lubuntu machine itself using 'connect to hidden network'.

The SSID was visible on my Android device immediately.

I saw that the iptables rules were created on Lubuntu by the Network Manager automatically. I was sharing a tethered usb Internet connection over the WiFi hotspot. I don't see a necessity for the 'cloned MAC address' field though.