# Wifi hotspot to connect to Android using Broadcom 43xx

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, android, broadcom

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 64b on a Dell Inspiron N5010.

My wireless device (found using `lspci`) is **Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)**.

I bought a new android phone and want to connect to Internet by using the laptop as a Wireless Access Point (ad-hoc doesn't work with Android).

I tried following tutorials like the one at [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode). The relevant output from `iw list` was

```
    Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
```

Running `sudo hostapd /path/to/conf/file` gave me (`eth1` is the wireless, verified by `iwconfig`)

```
Failed to create interface mon.eth1: -95 (Operation not supported)
Could not set channel for kernel driver
eth1: Unable to setup interface.
Could not connect to kernel driver.
```

**I am able to use *Connectify* and *Virtualrouter* on Windows, and the phone works great.**
How do I get an access point running on Ubuntu? I'm open to other alternatives as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to an open source driver did it

### Short Version

Using an open source driver (**brcmsmac** in my case) instead of the Proprietary Broadcom STA Wireless driver (**wl**) and installing [ap-hotspot](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html) did the trick

---

### Long version for Broadcom Users

1. Go to [Ubuntu Broadcomm WifiDocs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Identifying_Your_Broadcom_BCM43xx_Chipset_.28PCI.29). See if an open source alternative exists.
2. The [Linux drivers page](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers) should tell you if it supports AP mode

   - If so **yay!**
   - If not, I can't help. Sorry.
3. Temporarily switch to the open- driver source to check if it does what you want

   ```
   #unload all drivers
   sudo modprobe -r b43 bcma
   sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma
   sudo modprobe -r wl

   #load the corresponding open-source driver (brcmsmac in my case)
   sudo modprobe brcmsmac
   ```

   If it works, you can edit the blacklists to make sure only the required driver works. An easier option would be to simply uninstall the proprietary drivers using `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`
4. Install
   [ap-hotspot](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html).
   Remember, there are some issues in 14.04, and rolling back must be
   done as shown in the page. Else, use `hostapd` as described
   [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode)
5. Run `sudo ap-hotspot start`. Your android phone should work with this conection.
6. Open source wins again

Comment: I am on a Mac and for me only the proprietary driver works. Hence, I bought a router. They are cheap anyway and it is better

Comment: Ah, not all of us have that at our disposal.

Comment: Like I said, routers are pretty cheap :P

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the stuff which makes hotspots work is broken on Ubuntu 13.xx. I haven't found a fix yet anywhere on the internet.

Comment: would it work if I upgraded to 14.04

Comment: I haven't checked with 14.04