# Get wi-fi hotspot (access point mode) working in Trusty Tahr with Network Manager

Tags: networking, 14.04, network-manager, hot-spot

I have read that the NetworkManager is supposed to be capable of creating a hotspot in access point mode since version 0.9.8. I've got the NetworkManager installed that comes with Trusty Tahr (version 0.9.8.8). My networkcard supports AP. But I can't find an option in NetworkManager to create an access point mode hotspot. Maybe I'm missing a package? Or maybe I'm just too stupid to use the GUI properly?

[... not relevant anymore]

Comment: This worked easily and perfectly for me (Ubuntu 14.04 on an old acer netbook):
http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya looks like the new GUI is still missing AP mode. Fortunately you can use KDE's connection manager as described [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/)