# Password in WiFi hotspot in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, password, kde

I am using Wired internet. Want to create a WiFi hotspot using an USB Wireless router. I tried all the possible way discussed here in AskUbuntu like:

1. Followed step by step several times according to [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)
2. [Configure WIreless Hotspot Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498453/configure-wireless-hotspot-ubuntu-14-04-trusty)

I was able to create Access Point using both links but that doesn't work for me saying **Incorrect Password** in my 2 Android devices (Android version 4.3 and 5.0).

I also try to create a Hotspot searching for 3 days using the following method found in an other website:

1. Install KDE’s Network Manager.
2. Add a Wireless (shared) connection giving a name, ssid, and select Access Point mode.
3. From wireless security tab select "WPA & WPA2 Personal" and set a password.
4. Select my connection by clicking "Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi network" on Unity panel.

Then try to connect my android phone but failed. **After searching a lot I have found that many posted that having a password in Access Point not working.**  But nowhere a solution for that. Then I removed my password and it works.

My question is **why setting a password not working and how to set a password in access point using KDE’s Network Manager?**

Need help and thank you guys in advance.

Comment: This post http://www.linuxveda.com/2015/08/23/how-to-create-an-ap-in-ubuntu-15-04-to-connect-to-androidiphone/ claims to have hotspot working with a password set, it is 15.04 but you can try these steps.

Comment: @markkirby I have tried a [similar answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot/439530#439530) as like as your link and edited my question adding that link already. That also doesn't help me :(

Comment: @SiddiquiNoor I'm having the exact same problem (incorrect passwd on my android), did you resolve it?

Comment: @x0a not yet solved or find a way.