# How to create wifi hotspot on Ubuntu 14.04 that is visible to every device?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, network-manager, hot-spot

I was creating a wifi hotspot using **kde-nm-connection-editor** as instructed on [Share Internet Connection With Android in Ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/) but an unexpected error occurred as a result of which I was able to create it up. The following error appeared :

`(32) Access Point (AP) mode is not supported by this device.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Zeiss Ikon said, it seems that it doesn't support AP mode. Sadly this happens to me too.

You can run in a terminal `iw list` and check the **Supported interface modes:** section to see if there is any reference to **AP**. If not, then you can't use the AP mode.

Answer (score 0):

That error is reporting that your particular wifi hardware doesn't support operating as a hotspot.  There's nothing you can do in software to correct it, you can only replace the hardware  (though it would probably cost about the same to buy a cheap wifi router).

Comment: but it works perfectly well in Windows

Comment: I guess I should have said "is telling Ubuntu that it doesn't support operating as a hotsport".  It's possible, in this case, that you need a different driver.

Comment: I came with the same issue. Windows works just fine, but Ubuntu seems not able to start the hotspot. Even though if I saw "AP mode" in the iw list. Why does it happen?