# How do I make two ubuntu computers communicate with each other by controlling their wireless cards?

Tags: wireless, networking

I want to have data communication between two Ubuntu computers using wireless without the need of internet. I want them to transmit and receive wirelessly but I want to build my own communication process. Is there any tool/lib that allows me to control the wireless card? I want to have data communication, but I would like to define how and what data is transmuted between the two computers.

For now I would be glad with simple answers to:

1. How to connect two Ubuntu computers wirelessly without using the Internet
2. How to control data sent through a wireless card

I want to use python or java, but any answer will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set up one of the computers as an [AP WiFi hotspot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot?s=1|0.0000)
2. Use [NitroShare](http://nitroshare.net) to actually send/receive data

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare-dev
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nitroshare
   ```

As NitroShare is FLOSS, you can fork the [C++ code](https://github.com/nitroshare/nitroshare-desktop) if it would not meet your needs or even better: start contributing!  The NitroShare author is active on Ask Ubuntu, so drop by in the chat room if you're willing to do this.

Comment: Will Nitroshare discover devices not connected to my network? I want to create a network of all devices (fridge, disk, sensor) and make them communicate without internet. Then, if one of the discovered devices has internet connection, all will). Kind of transforming tcp/ip on a p2p. This way with enough devices close to each other(mine and neighbour, and all the world) there would be no need to have an ISP. Like if you could transform all existing routers to communicate with the closest neighbour router instead of connecting to your ISP.

Comment: No. Nitroshare will do one thing and one thing only and do it extremely efficiently: send/Receive files from connected devices running all sorts of OSes...  What you're trying to do needs #1 but all the other stuff would be [a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) entirely.

Comment: @lapisdecor: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**