# Ubuntu 14.04 Hotspot automatic creation

Tags: networking, hot-spot

I'm using the default hotspot interface in Ubuntu 14.04 through Network Manager, but I want to automate the creation of the hotspot when the laptop is connected through Ethernet.

Is there at least a way of activating the hotspot with a command?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the way to manage the default Network Manager with the command line. I need to use the command `nmcli`:

```
nmcli -p con up id "Hotspot"
```

I still need to create some sort of logic. A command with an if statement that activates the hotspot if eth0 is active but I am having troubles figuring it out.

With this command maybe I can work with the logic

```
nmcli -t -f device,state d
```

Answer (score 0):

If not you mentioned automation, I think your answer might be this:
[How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)

A bit more of searching would do.

Comment: This comment put me in the way of finding the answer I needed.