# Problem with Installing ap-hotspot

Tags: internet, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

Output (Error Part for last command):

```
E: Unable to locate package hostpd
```

I'm going to install ap-hotspot, but it seems, there is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last question, I'm assuming you're using 15.04. [You can see](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8?field.series_filter=vivid) that the webupd8 PPA doesn't have an `ap-hotspot` package for Vivid yet.

What software is in a repo is really up to the repo maintainer. In this case, [Andrew of Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/p/about.html).

Comment: So what package should I install?

Answer (score 2):

In fact there's no `hostpd` package in `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` even for 14.04

Try to install it this way:

```
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot hostapd dnsmasq iw
```

`Ap-hotspot` depends on those three packages listed as followed in a command above.

Comment: Error is still up!

Comment: probably because it's trying to install a package `hostpd` which is named `hostapd`, let me try to install it and see.

Comment: well in my case it grabs the right package `hostapd` probably as *Oli* said it's unvailable for 15.04 yet if you're using it.

Comment: The old hostapd package ap-hotspot needs is now at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/ - bear in mind it does not have the security fixes of the newer versions that have replaced it.... and if ap-hotspot fails, you can try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot).