# Return to default iptables behavior after activating ip forwarding with hostapd

Tags: networking, wireless, server, iptables, wireless-access-point

I followed [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/q/180733/300807) on how to create a wifi network with hostapd, assign IP addresses, and forward connections to another network interface. I have not yet set up the IP forwarding yet, because I have yet to find a way to reverse the forwarding. Could someone please a. Explain what IP Masquerading actually does, b. explain what exactly each part `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/16 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE` does so that I and future readers can better understand and be able to use the iptables command, and most importantly c. Tell a simple way to reverse it without restarting the computer. I have moderate experience with Linux command line and how it works so explanations of basic usage are not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic setup of `iptables`. This will delete all old `rules` and `chains`, allows any outbound connection.

```
sudo service iptables stop
#################################################
# clear existing chains
#################################################

sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables --delete-chain

#################################################
# allow loopback
#################################################

sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# allow all ICMP
#################################################

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# allow established connections
#################################################

sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#################################################
# deny all
#################################################

sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

#################################################
# default policies
#################################################

sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

#################################################
# save the new policy
#################################################

sudo service iptables save
```

Your `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/16 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE` means

Append `-A` this rule to the `nat` table: after routing decision `POSTROUTING`, for source network `-s 10.10.0.0/16`, on outbound interface `ppp0` and do nat `-j MASQUERADE`

`MASQUERADE` is `nat`. On output interface mask source IP address with address from interface. `NAT` is network address translation. More about nat can be found [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)

Edit 1

Any added rule `sudo iptables -t nat -A rest_of_rule` you can remove with `sudo iptables -t nat -D rest_of_rule` Only replase `-A` aka append with `-D` aka delete.

example 2

add

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

remove

```
sudo iptables -D INPUT -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I was wondering if there was any way to just reverse the one change, which if I understand correctly after any request from 10.10.0.(2-17) request has been routed or denied with previous rules, sends the request out via ppp0 without telling the destination the source IP.

Comment: BTW I would definitely upvote but I don't have the rep. If somebody upvotes my question I will have enough rep and will immediately upvote. :)

Comment: Any added rule `sudo iptables -t nat -A rest_of_rule` you can remove with `sudo iptables -t nat -D rest_of_rule` Only replade `-A` aka append with `-D` aka delete.