# Hotspot created and connected from linux but no internet access on phone

Tags: networking, iptables

I wanted to create a hotspot with this tutorial : [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)

Part : Whether your wireless card support Access Point mode.

When i tried manually , i think it was good but i'm not sure because 3g data was activated in background :/.

But after tried their script and modify a litlle because it does not work on my linux , i think that i screwed up iptables when i flush them or anything, i don't know really. Now i have a "!" on the wifi on my phone and i can't have internet on this but i'm connected on the hotspot. So i don't know where is the problem , i think it's not very complicated but after 3 hours and try a lot of without success,  Really i don't understand what is my problem :/.

I hope that you will can help me. I don't found all iptables , if you have any command that you want i write , i will do that :).

```
Lenovo-Flex-2-14:~$ sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Thank you for your help and sorry if for the beggin i haven't code or anything to give you in this case :/

PS : Phone : android 5.1 ( not very important i guess ) 
     Computer : Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will tell you a step by step procedure for setting up a hotspot in ubuntu and sharing your Internet with it (with less headache).
First you need to install two packages

```
sudo apt-get install hostapd bridge-utils
```

Now edit **/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf** with (If not present create it)

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
ssid=YOUR_SSID
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=YOUR_PASSWORD
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
macaddr_acl=0
```

Make it live by Editing **/etc/default/hostapd**, set the line to be:

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

Now Bridge the network connections. Open **/etc/network/interfaces**.
Assuming that eth0 is the internet source of your system. Change the configuration something like this.(Make sure to remove iface wlan0)

```
#loopback adapter
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#wired adapter
iface eth0 inet dhcp
#bridge
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
```

Make hostapd to be run everytime on boot:

```
sudo update-rc.d hostapd enable
```

Now reboot..
You can start or stop hostapd with

```
sudo service hostapd stop
```

or

```
sudo service hostapd start
```

> Note: Booting may take a little time if one/both  of the interface
>   fails (eth0 wlan0). For example, if you are using an external usb wifi
>   card and removed it while booting, Bridging will fail, hence increase
>   in overall booting time.

Comment: thank you , but even after to follow your tuto, ,on my phone i see the wireless but during the connexion , i get the message : "authentification error" and it can't to connect at this network :/. Any idea ?

Comment: Oki sorry , it was the password , i forgot to edit so the network bugged ... now work like a charm , think you , it was so easy intead of dhcp etc where this take me 6hours ^

Comment: NB : if i could , i would give you +1 but i haven't much reputations :/ . I created a script if  that can be usefull for someone : https://github.com/kevincaradant/script_hotspot_linux.git . Sorry for the repository ( new repo ) , i rewrite more later the read me :)

Comment: Mhh just a question , i don't remember if it was like that at the beginning , but Ethernet and Wifi are " Device Not Managed " when i modify with your config on /etc/network/interfaces , so i can't put my vpn on Ethernet :/ , is it possible ?

Comment: http://imgur.com/V8362wg this is my network manager

Comment: try putting the vpn on br0 instead, in the terminal way

Comment: Must I to follow this tuto : http://powtos.fr/255-openvpn-bridge/ ? It seems to be complicated because you have to edit the server and also the client with a bridge from eth0 to tap0(vpn) and then with your way , in /etc/network/interface , you have to create an other bridge from tap0 to wlan0 ? or i have nothing understood :/. If you have an idea @Sijin Krishnan i listen you ;)

Answer (score 1):

The same symptoms, different issue – Docker blocked forwarding on the computer ([ticket](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/43719)).

Can be resolved via:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Same here (debian). Note that your network interface names might be different, find out with `ip a s` (address show).