# Can the hotspot created in XUbuntu visible to windows devices?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, network-manager, android

I created a wifi hotspot in Xubuntu following the steps in :  [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot/180734#180734).

However I noticed the following : 
1. My OnePlus one device was able to see the wifi hotspot - it said, it is saved, but would NEVER connect to the hotspot. 
2. My second windows phone nor my windows laptop are able to detect the hotspot at all.

However, my friends mac detected it and was able to browse the internet using my hotspot.   so I am not sure if I am missing something on my
a. OnePlus device and
b. Windows devices.

Should the hotspot work my windows and Cyanogen devices by default or should I be installing some packages for making it work ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the hot-spot correctly it should be able to use on a separate Windows computer & any mobile device! When I use my hot-spot (created on Ubuntu 14.04lts) My windows does not automatically detect it I must manually enter the "Hidden Networks" To see it & had to set it up in Windows "Network Settings" -> Create a network" This could be for several reasons including hardware and may be different on case by case situations. Unfortunately i do not have a "Cyanogen device" to test but my Android connects just fine. Hope this will help you troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please remember to click the ChecK MarK for Answers That solved your issue!