# Cannot start created Wifi Access point in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, wireless-access-point

My target is to create a Wifi hotspot using a wifi USB adapter in my computer that is already wireless connected.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS / 64 bit
The USB adapter is a: TP-Link TL-WN823N

This post describes exactly how to do this: [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)

In short there are 4 steps:

1.) Create the initial hotspot entry by:
    System Settings > Network > Use as hotspot

2.) Edit the created hotspot using GUI Networking > Edit Connections
    Add SSID, WPA2, password etc.

3.) Since the ap mode cannot be set in the GUI yet is must be done with 
    the command line.

```
'sudo -i gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot'
```

4.) Start the now correctly defined hotspot

This is the point where I got stuck and reason for asking this question.
The previous mentioned post says:

*"Click on 'Create New Wi-Fi Network' from Network Indicator menu."*

There is a field "connection" that allows you to create a new connection of select an existing one. The intention is to select the hotspot that is created before.

However, for me it is only possible to create a new hotspot because the field "connection" is missing. See picture.

[no connection to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yYt1.png)

What I can do is select one of both adapters. That is good because I want the USB wifi and not the laptop adapter. If I type the new network name in the field "network name" a NEW network is created that shows up in '/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/'

So that doesn't help. However I noticed that it was possible to use: 
"connect to a hidden wifi network". The created network is in the list and is selectable. Starting the wifi gives the error: "Failed to activate the connection"."AP mode is not supported by this device"

Any help would be appreciated.
I want to stick to the basic functionality of Ubuntu as much as possible.
I do not want to install ap-hotspot. Yes, it might be working but is not maintained any longer.

Comment: I don't think it is possible using one wifi adapter in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Install `iw`

`sudo apt-get install iw`

type the following command:

```
iw list
```

the output is something like

```
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * AP/VLAN
     * monitor
     * mesh point
```

If you can't see **AP** , you need to setting up your Wifi Adapter to support **master mode**

visit `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode`
to get more informations how to setting up wifi adapter to support master mode

2) Using create_ap

```
  git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
  cd create_ap
 make install
```

Examples

No passphrase (open network):

```
  create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint
```

WPA + WPA2 passphrase:

```
  create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

AP without Internet sharing:

```
  create_ap -n wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Bridged Internet sharing:

```
    create_ap -m bridge wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Bridged Internet sharing (pre-configured bridge interface):

```
    create_ap -m bridge wlan0 br0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Internet sharing from the same WiFi interface:

```
   create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Choose a different WiFi adapter driver

```
   create_ap --driver rtl871xdrv wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

replace `rtl871xdrv` with your adapter

No passphrase (open network) using pipe:

```
    echo -e "MyAccessPoint" | create_ap wlan0 eth0
```

WPA + WPA2 passphrase using pipe:

```
    echo -e "MyAccessPoint\nMyPassPhrase" | create_ap wlan0 eth0
```

Enable IEEE 802.11n

```
    create_ap --ieee80211n --ht_capab '[HT40+]' wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Source `https://github.com/oblique/create_ap`

Comment: Hi GAD3R,  I was able to switch the device into master mode using: 'iwconfig wlan1 mode master'. This works. I checked if the device supports AP interface mode. 'iw list' shows AP mode. But I think that is not correct is likely the laptop device rather than the usb device. 'iw dev wlan1 list' does not work. Suggestions?

Comment: Dr.Zuse i edit my answer to give you more informations

Comment: Hi GAD3R,  thanx for updating. **iw list** only sees my laptop internal wifi device(wlan0). I can put my usb wifi into _master_ mode but I still do not know if the device supports AP mode.

Comment: **create_ap** has impressive capabilities but first developer oblique also has an impressive reputation. Ubuntu was designed to have access point functionality (although not working by gui yet...) My personal preference is to stick to released ubuntu code. I will do the very obvious thing to do: just switch adapter. My build in adapter supports AP mode and the usb wifi adapter can be the input wifi. Thanx anyway.