# How can I make hotspot on my dell 2520 laptop with ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, hot-spot, dell-vostro

I have just installed ubuntu 15.10 in my dell vostro 2520 laptop. I am unable to make my laptop as a wifi hotspot. I am using internet on this laptop through a LAN cable. There is no wireless option in the Network button of the system setting option. I have not installed any driver, since I do not know how to get the driver for a Vostro with ubuntu OS.

Comment: For me the solution in http://askubuntu.com/a/349844/16395 reliably worked from 12.04 to 14.04. Not checked in new releases. Of course, you need your wifi working to do anything --- so having it going is a priority.