# Hotspot made by Ubuntu is not visible in any Android phone

Tags: networking, android, hot-spot, wireless-access-point, ap-hotspot

I tried to create a hotspot from network manager. The hotspot started correctly but it is not visible in any android phone.

I tried this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot) and followed the steps as given, but it didn't work.

Output of `iw list`

```
 Wiphy phy0
max # scan SSIDs: 1
max scan IEs length: 0 bytes
Retry short limit: 7
Retry long limit: 4
Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
Supported Ciphers:
    * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
    * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
    * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
    * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
    * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
Band 1:
    Bitrates (non-HT):
        * 1.0 Mbps
        * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
        * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
        * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
        * 6.0 Mbps
        * 9.0 Mbps
        * 12.0 Mbps
        * 18.0 Mbps
        * 24.0 Mbps
        * 36.0 Mbps
        * 48.0 Mbps
        * 54.0 Mbps
    Frequencies:
        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
        * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
Band 2:
    Bitrates (non-HT):
        * 6.0 Mbps
        * 9.0 Mbps
        * 12.0 Mbps
        * 18.0 Mbps
        * 24.0 Mbps
        * 36.0 Mbps
        * 48.0 Mbps
        * 54.0 Mbps
    Frequencies:
        * 5170 MHz [34] (disabled)
        * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5190 MHz [38] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5210 MHz [42] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5230 MHz [46] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5500 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5520 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5540 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5560 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5580 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5600 MHz [120] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5620 MHz [124] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5640 MHz [128] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5660 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5680 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5700 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 2274 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5745 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5765 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5785 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5805 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5825 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5920 MHz [184] (disabled)
        * 5940 MHz [188] (disabled)
        * 5960 MHz [192] (disabled)
        * 5980 MHz [196] (disabled)
        * 6000 MHz [200] (disabled)
        * 6020 MHz [204] (disabled)
        * 6040 MHz [208] (disabled)
        * 6060 MHz [212] (disabled)
        * 6080 MHz [216] (disabled)
Supported commands:
     * set_interface
     * new_key
     * join_ibss
     * set_pmksa
     * del_pmksa
     * flush_pmksa
     * connect
     * disconnect
software interface modes (can always be added):
interface combinations are not supported
Device supports scan flush.
```

means driver doesn't show AP.

```
Supported interface modes:
 * IBSS
 * managed
```

Even though it works on Connectify and Virtualrouter in windows.

So how can I make my hotspot visible to my Android phone?