# Hotspot upgrade to wpa2

Tags: networking, network-manager, hot-spot, wpa2

I use my notebook as a hotspot(through a wired connection), but if i want to change te security setting. The only 2 options i get is WEP or WEP sentence. and thats not enough to connect a windows device. i have ubuntu 16.04.1(LTS), on my notebook.

So is there an way to upgrade my hotspot to WPA2, i think its possible because on windows i always had wpa2.

PS you may need some info of my notebook, please say how i could get you that info.

With kind regards,

Aaron

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Maybe this is a left-over from an old install.  Have you tried creating a new Wi-Fi Hotspot (with a different name) and just go to the Wi-Fi Security tab and activate WPA2) ???

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer, in [this manual](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot/180734#180734). You have to save te hotspot first as a hotspot. And then after you save it open again and switch to wpa2.

I did not know the difference between ad-hoc and hotspot.

Anyway thanks :D