# Can I enable WPA2 HotSpot Encryption?

Tags: 18.04, encryption, hot-spot, wpa2

### My Situation

I'm running the latest **Ubuntu 18.04** and I'm capable of opening a WEP encrypted hotspot, but for security reasons I'd like to avoid WEP and use WPA2 instead.  Needless to say, opening `nm-connection-editor` doesn't let me choose any other options in the Security tab, so here I am.

### What I've tried

I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840487/hotspot-upgrade-to-wpa2) regarding pretty much my issue, which in turn points to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot/180734#180734), with more details explained, however I got confused in certain areas.

According to the second thread, determining whether or not a wireless device supports Wireless Access Points (WPA) comes down to using the `iw list` command and looking for an "AP" element in the output Supported Interface Modes list. Makes sense, however my output list lacks the "AP" and I can run a HotSpot just fine, so I had a hard time following any further.

### Is It a Drivers Issue?

I have a dual boot set up on my PC, I used to run **Windows 10** exclusively before I installed Ubuntu next to it. **Windows 10 is capable of creating a WPA2 protected HotSpot with my device!** The only thing I can think of that would be different between the operating systems is my drivers, but I'm only given one option in the *Software & Updates* menu, which is proprietary and should function correctly.

### Bottom Line

I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me:

1. What dictates the availability of certain WAP encryption types in Ubuntu,
2. What can I do to enable WPA2 (and if it's not possible, why?)

Comment: Hi, Just for Clarification are WPA and WPA2 same? when I tried to create Hotspot.. it says WPA & WPA2 Personnel in the security tab of nm-connection-editor

Comment: @PRATAP Well, in practice WPA2 is not the same as WPA, but if the option you're given mentions them both, then I guess it counts as WPA2.

Comment: When I did `lshw` it showed ap in some of the properties