# How to make an access point with Ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, system-installation, permissions

So, I am trying to figure out how to setup up an Ubuntu server to be an access point between the modem and router. I want it to have x amount of accounts, x being 1 - infinite, that rang from having full access, limited access, to no access. Just the control on access to no access would be great. [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k39l.png) for a diagram.

Comment: What do you mean by "access point"?  Do you want people to be able to log in, or are you talking about setting up some kind of server?  If you answer in a comment, please put my user name preceded by an ampersand in the comment, like "@username", or else I won't see it.

Comment: @rclocher3 I want people to have to login in first. However I want user1 to have access to the intranet and the internet, but user2 to have only intranet and not internet.

Comment: Oh, now I get it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)

Comment: @rclocher3 It is, however, I like to bridge the modem and router with the server and have accounts that block access to the modem or allows access to the modem. That make sense?

Comment: Kinda like print sharing. Where one account has access to the printer and another doesn't. I need that with the internet however.

Comment: I'm no expert in such things, but my hunch is that what you're asking for doesn't exist out of the box.  For a developer, it wouldn't be hard to write though.  Don't take my word for it though, do the research (web searches), maybe it does exist!