# Hotspot not visible

Tags: wireless

i use ubuntu 16.04.i have an ethernet connection and tried to share it using hotspot.the hotspot gets switched on in computer but is not visible in any phone.Please suggest a solution.My laptop is lenovo flex-2-14.i use ubuntu alongside windows 10 home.

Comment: 16.04 or 16.10? Please edit your question and while you're at it also post hardware specs (WiFi device) and how did you configured the hotspot.

Comment: i use 16.04.my laptop is Lenovo flex-2 14.i went to the network manager and clicked the button use as hotspot.the default hotspot was switched on.it is used along with windows 10, i mean dualboot.

Comment: The same model may come with a variety of different WiFi devices. The main point is to determine whether or not the WiFi works already because if not then obviously an hotspot cannot work either. Does it work when use instead of Ethernet?

Comment: wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off  .This is what is get when i run the command iwconfig

Comment: i only have an ethernet.i don't have a wifi.so i could'nt try.

Comment: in windows it is possible to share the ethernet using 160Wifi software.but in ububntu it is not workiing

Comment: and my device is BCM43142 802.11b/g/n

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: so should i follow the instructions given in the page?

Comment: will u please explain what was the problem?

Comment: i followed the instructions on the page.by deafault a hotspot in setup.But that itself is not visible in my phone.

Comment: The duplicate link is for you to install the proper drivers and confirm the WiFi is working.

Comment: i tried the link you have given.still the same result.hotspot is on but not visible in phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup an Access Point mode Wi-Fi Hotspot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot)

Comment: it says connection is not available at the device wlp2s0 at this time