# How share WiFi's internet as hotspot in 16.04

Tags: wireless, internet, sharing, hot-spot

I saw thread discussing the same. But they are not focusing on 16.04. In simple words, I want someone else use my laptop's internet ( WiFi ) through a custom hotspot. How is it possible ?

Comment: Are you sure things have no improved since the " possible answer "? I did read that solution. The screen shots were not matching what I have in 16.04. Also, no solution like Connectify available yet ?

Comment: Just to be clear, is your device connected to Internet via WiFi, *and* you're trying to share that same connection via WiFi? If so, you would need to have two separate wireless cards. You can't use a single card to both gain Internet access and share that Internet access.

Comment: If you want to share your Internet connection over WiFi, you're either going to have to connect your computer to the Internet using an ethernet cable or you'll have to get a second wireless card (probably USB).

Comment: I just tested the instructions in the first answer of this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot on my 16.04 desktop install and the screens match exactly.

Comment: The duplicates are years old and do not work. I have a 14 system and a 16 system. The instructions in the duplicates work for 14 but not for 16. This should not have been voted duplicate! They're different systems and while you might assume they "should work" this isn't always the case.