# Unable to connect to Ubuntu 16.04 Wi-Fi Hotspot (wont accept password)

Tags: 16.04, networking, ap-hotspot

I want to share my wired internet connection with wireless devices. I was able to get a wifi hotspot running by following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/439530/421131)

Eventually I was able to get my android devices to detect my wifi. Unfortunately, when I try to connect, it always rejects my password. I've tried many combinations of passwords and devices but I am unable to get it to connect, it always says "Incorrect password."

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to get a wireless hotspot working! but not with Ubuntu's built-in hotspot, rather with hostapd and [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap)

create_ap is a great utility that simplifies the use of hostapd. To use, all you need to do is install hostapd and create_ap with

```
sudo apt-get install hostapd
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap.git && cd create_ap && make install
```

Then to start a wireless hotspot

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

To get your wireless back:

```
CTRL^C
create_ap --fix-unmanaged
```

Comment: Did you had a password with more than 8 characters in length?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't let you set up a hotspot otherwise (neither the built-in Ubuntu hotspot or hostapd)