# WiFi Hotspot and Domain Name

Tags: networking, dns, hot-spot

I managed to activate a WiFi Hotspot on my Ubuntu 18.04 server: see this [SO-question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot).

Now I can already connect my Android Tablet to this hotspot and also reach a webserver on the Ubuntu server, when I enter the IP address in the browser: e.g. `http://10.4.4.4`

**Is it possible to configure the Hotspot so that users can connect using a domain name instead of the IP address?**
e.g. `http://myubuntu.com` instead of the ip address?

I thought that it should be possible to start a DNS server on my Ubuntu and configure the Hotspot to use it. But in the `nm-connection-editor` the DNS servers field is deactivated
[image]

Comment: The problem is telling your tablet to use the DNS on your server. If the address it gets is assigned using the DHCP protocol (which assumes that your server also runs a DHCP server), then the DHCP config can include setting the DNS server as well.

Comment: I simply used `Turn on WiFi-Hotspot` in `Settings` - `WiFi` and my tablet already got a correct IP address (in the 10.4.4.x range) when I connected to the Hotspot. So it seems that the Hotspot (on the Ubuntu server) already acts as a DHCP server, right?

Comment: If it does it can likely be configured to pass the DNS setup to DHCP clients.

Comment: That's what I think too. And the `DNS servers` edit box seems the perfect place for this. But for some reason it is deactivated...