# ubuntu 18.04 hotspot not visible

Tags: wireless, hot-spot

I'm Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and trying to share internet from 3g Huawei modem to android phone. I followed [these steps](https://www.debugpoint.com/2018/05/create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu-android-support/), but Hotspot not visible on android devices:
[image: the hotspot settings on my machine]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to share your Wireless connection via hotspot?

Comment: I'm trying to share internet from modem 3g huawei to android phone @pomsky

Comment: Instead of a live 3G connection, disable that, and try using a wired LAN connection, and see if the hotspot works now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and fixed it by changing the WiFi hotspot setting on my device from 5GHz to 2.5GHz.

[image: hotspot problem]

Comment: Could you explain why you think this will solve OP's problem?

Comment: I had also the same problem. By changing the hotspot band from 5GHz to 2.5 GHz, everything started to work.

Comment: It works for me. Thanks, Ralf

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen because the ops device may be set to default 5ghz? Can you explain why it wouldn't?

Answer (score 2):

Had similar problem on a 19.04 upgraded machine which worked fine in 18.04...google found no answer, so decided to go back to basics. Looked in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot` and lo and behold buried in the `[Wifi]` section was a line;

```
Hidden=true
```

Change it to `Hidden=false` and bingo the hotspot became visible to all android and iOS devices instantly.

Hopefully this might give you some clue to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The security in your hotspot is "WEP"
whereas for a 'wireless hotspot' you need to make it "WPA"
Try changing your settings for this matter
--Hope it helps

Comment: where I can find  the security settings ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot/180734#180734

follow this guide.. If it helps, do mark the answer as solved