# How to make an IPV6 only hotspot on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ipv6, hot-spot

I'm trying to create an IPV6 only network in Ubuntu.

I used [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot) to create the hotspot and that worked.

In order to make it IPV6 only using `nm-connection-editor`, I disabled IPV4 and checked the "Require IPV6 addressing for this connection to complete box" in the IPV6 window.

This did not change much.
The hotspot still works and is still using IPV4.

Help would be appreciated.