# detailed how to or example needed to setup an access point using netplan

Tags: netplan, wireless-access-point

As headline stated: I am looking for instructions on how to setup an access point using netplan, including setting up a bridge between eth0 and wlan0. DHCP Server would be my router, to which the system is connected via eth0. I am running Ubuntu Server 18.04. 
(I used to be able to do it following examples using ifupdown and hostapd, but now I need to stay with netplan..)

- What packages need to be installed for this?
- Beside setting up a yaml file, what needs to be done?
- where is the bridge (i.e.br0) defined?
- where are credentails like ssid and password  set?
- Could you share an example yaml file (i.e. with eth0 wlan0) for the above scenario?
  (I need a solution without using iptables, as this can not be used in my system)

As I am far from being an expert, the more detailed the instructions, the better....

Answer (score 12):

I got it to work with the help of these links: [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1133533/1060413), [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/180734/1060413), [3](https://netplan.io/examples), [4](https://fabianlee.org/2019/04/01/kvm-creating-a-bridged-network-with-netplan-on-ubuntu-bionic/)

This is the sequence, which worked for me (WiFi in n-Mode, static IP):

- Install hostapd: `apt-get update`, `apt-get install hostapd`
- unmask & enable it: `sudo systemctl unmask hostapd`, `sudo systemctl enable hostapd`
- create /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf and cut&paste:

> ```
> # the interface used by the AP
> interface=wlan0
> driver=nl80211
> # "g" simply means 2.4GHz band
> hw_mode=g
> # the channel to use
> channel=1
> # limit the frequencies used to those allowed in the country
> ieee80211d=1
> # the country code
> country_code=DE
> # 802.11n support
> ieee80211n=1
> # QoS support
> wmm_enabled=1
> # the name of the AP
> ssid=yourSSID
> macaddr_acl=0
> # 1=wpa, 2=wep, 3=both
> auth_algs=1
> ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
> # WPA2 only
> wpa=2
> wpa_passphrase=yourpassphrase
> wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
> #wpa_pairwise=TKIP
> rsn_pairwise=CCMP
> ```

- Edit the file /etc/default/hostapd and modify the line of DAEMON_CONF like this: `DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"`

(Testing to verify is AP is visible i.e. on phone: `sudo service hostapd start`; then `sudo service hostapd stop` again to continue setup)

- cut&paste this into `/etc/netplan/network.yaml file (no tabs, just spaces, follow indentation exactly - yaml is picky...):

> ```
> network:
>   version: 2
>   renderer: networkd
>   ethernets:
>     # My Ethernet adapter
>     eth0:
>       # For some reason it seems I must specify at least something here.
>       dhcp4: no
>     # My Wi-Fi adapter
>     wlan0:
>       dhcp4: no
>   bridges:
>     br0:
>       interfaces:
>         - eth0
>         - wlan0
>       # Using a static IP for this box.
>       addresses:
>         - 192.168.1.xxx/24
>       gateway4: 192.168.1.x
>       nameservers:
>         addresses: [1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1]
> ```

- Apply the new configuration: `sudo netplan generate`,`sudo netplan apply`

Comment: Works great for me, even with Ubuntu 20.04.