# Wifi + Wired Hot-spot possible?

Tags: wireless, network-bridge, hot-spot, wired

Running Ubuntu 20.04. I want to setup a wifi hot-spot which distributes IPs by dhcp. Furthermore I want to connect to this 'hot-spot' by wired ethernet connection. So the wired connection shall be in the same subnet as the wifi hot-spot and shall also distribute IPs by dhcp. I found some tutorials how to setup a hot-spot. I also read that the connection between wifi and wire can be setup by a bridge. But I have no idea how to merge these two approaches. Any hints ?

Comment: So, to confirm, the notebook would act as both a DHCP provider and a wireless access point, yes?

Comment: Yes, thats the idea.

Comment: Well, [this will give you a hotspot](https://askubuntu.com/a/439530/1222991) and [part of this answer to the same question](https://askubuntu.com/a/180734/1222991) will give you a DHCP server that can be used on the network. Be sure to configure your network router to point machines to the correct IP to obtain a network address and you’ll be good 

Comment: Would you mind providing a bit more detail about your network? I'm not sure that I'm understanding you correctly. Why does your DHCP server need internet?   ...I just reread and I think I see what you're trying to accomplish. So hotspot & DHCP server are on same machine and clients will connect to this machine via network cable tethering? Is this correct?

Comment: The machine you are describing is just a standard router. Almost every router has both a built-in DHCP server and a hotspot via network cable. Are you trying to set up a LAN without a router? Essentially, you're describing ING every modern router's two main duties: provide a hotspot and issue / track network IPs.

Comment: Is there some other functionality that you need which  cheap router will not provide?

Comment: The very first hit searching for 'ubuntu router':  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router

Comment: Thanks to all of you. So I need to configure a router with wifi and ethernet support. My problem was that is was looking for the wrong setup (hotspot, bridge...). Stupid me...