# Ubuntu AP not assigning IP address

Tags: networking, network-manager, wireless-access-point

I am running Ubuntu 20.4 and via the settings GUI I configured it as access point to share the wired connection to other devices (ubuntu computer, android smartphones).

The access point starts, the other devices see the SSID, password is correct, but the access point does not assign them an IP address; client devices wait for an IP address forever...

With

```
ifconfig -a
```

I see the AP ip address, netmask and gateway (10.42.0.1/24)

I statically assigned addresses to the other devices (10.42.0.2...5) and they can access the internet.

What shall I do so that the AP serves ip addresses to the connecting clients ?

One would expect that all needed pieces work automatically... Shall I install a DHCP server ?

Any help highly appreciated.

P.S. I have a second, less relevant question :

```
nm-connection-editor
```

doesn't allow me to change channel number. The field is not editable.

What shall I do to chanhe channel number ?

Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-create-a-wi-fi-hotspot-in-access-point-mode

Comment: Not sure if I correctly understand your question, but I believe the answer is *yes, you need a DHCP server* if you wish to have dynamically assigned IPs.

Comment: when a client connects to the AP, it doesn't get an IP address, so it cannot access the internet. It seems odd to me that the gnome interface has a simple way to start the access point to share the wired connection, but you need to install something else in order to have it working...isn't it ?

Comment: @Terrance that's exactly what I did on my 20.04, the client doesn't get an IP address, though. I turn on the Wifi hotspot but it does not allow clients to share the internet connection. (whilst the dialog windows says it should). That's why I as: should I install a DHCP server before activating the hotspot ? If yes, it seems to me It should be documented..

Comment: One of the answers I included says yes to install the DHCP server.  One question, do you want the wireless devices on the same network as the wired devices?  Or do you want them on their own like they are now?

Comment: on their own. so yes, I will install a DHCP server.
but shouldn't it be the automatic behaviour  when starting the access point from the GUI ?